# Why doesn't decodeURI("a+b") == "a b"?

Tags: javascript, ruby, urlencode, decode, encode

I'm trying to encode URLs in Ruby and decode them with Javascript. However, the plus character is giving me weird behavior.

In Ruby:

```
[Dev]> CGI.escape "a b"
=> "a+b"
[Dev]> CGI.unescape "a+b"
=> "a b"
```

So far so good. But what about Javascript?

```
>>> encodeURI("a b")
"a%20b"
>>> decodeURI("a+b")
"a+b"
```

Basically I need a method of encoding / decoding URLs that works the same way in Javascript and Ruby.

**Edit:** `decodeURIComponent` is no better:

```
>>> encodeURIComponent("a b")
"a%20b"
>>> decodeURIComponent("a+b")
"a+b"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at `URI.encode` and `URI.decode`:

```
require 'uri'

URI.encode('a + b') # => "a%20+%20b"
URI.decode('a%20+%20b') # => "a + b"
```

An alternate, that I use a lot, is [`Addressable::URI`](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable):

```
require 'addressable/uri'
Addressable::URI.encode('a + b') #=> "a%20+%20b"
Addressable::URI.unencode('a%20+%20b') #=> "a + b"
```

Comment: Ok, nice! Is there any reason to *ever* use `CGI.escape`? (Or was it just put there to trick me!)

Comment: Also, note that `URI.encode` is deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824126/whats-the-difference-between-uri-escape-and-cgiescape/2832003#2832003

Comment: @Horace Loeb, then use Addressable::URI.

Comment: [URI.(un)escape deprecated?](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/207489) discusses the decision.

Comment: `Addressable::URI` looks cool, but leaving the standard library is too much overhead. I'll go with `URI.encode`

Answer (score 30):

`+` is not considered a space. One workaround is to replace `+` with `%20` and then call `decodeURIComponent`

Taken from php.js' [urldecode](http://phpjs.org/functions/urldecode):

```
decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
```

Comment: '+' is what space encodes to in a query. See the final sentence in [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding). It's not the same as a space in the parameters for a URL, which would encode as '%20'.

Comment: Thanks. Your decoding works fine. There is still one question left.
Could you please explain WHY the plus sign is not considered as a space?

Comment: @VictorYarema I can't tell you how it came to be that way. But the issue is query strings are considered `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - _not_ URIs. And that MIME has a rule that says spaces must be encoded as `+`. Relevant section: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

Answer (score 4):

[From MDC decodeURI:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

> Does not decode escape sequences that could not have been introduced by encodeURI.

[From MDC encodeURI:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

> Note that encodeURI by itself cannot form proper HTTP GET and POST requests, such as for XMLHTTPRequests, because "&", "+", and "=" are not encoded

Answer (score -1):

You also get the same problem of a+b when sending a response from php via XMLHttpRequest if you use php urlencode. To solve it you have to use the php rawurlencode function.

From XMLHttpRequest to php urldecode works fine for some reason.

Comment: How does this answer address the question? It is asking about JavaScript and Ruby, not PHP.