# How to convert URL parameters to a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, url, url-parameters, url-parsing

I have a string like this:

```
abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5
```

How can I convert it into a JavaScript object like this?

```
{
  abc: 'foo',
  def: '[asf]',
  xyz: 5
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: It's not: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get#Example
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams#Example
(though we'll have to wait a little while longer for all browsers to have picked this up)

Comment: Object.fromEntries(Array.from(new URLSearchParams('abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5')))

Answer (score 465, accepted):

## In the year 2021... Please consider this obsolete.

## Edit

This edit improves and explains the answer based on the comments.

```
var search = location.search.substring(1);
JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')
```

**Example**

Parse `abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5` in five steps:

- decodeURI: abc=foo&def=[asf]&xyz=5
- Escape quotes: same, as there are no quotes
- Replace &: `abc=foo","def=[asf]","xyz=5`
- Replace =: `abc":"foo","def":"[asf]","xyz":"5`
- Suround with curlies and quotes: `{"abc":"foo","def":"[asf]","xyz":"5"}`

which is legal JSON.

An **improved solution** allows for more characters in the search string. It uses a reviver function for URI decoding:

```
var search = location.search.substring(1);
JSON.parse('{"' + search.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}', function(key, value) { return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) })
```

**Example**

```
search = "abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5&foo=b%3Dar";
```

gives

```
Object {abc: "foo", def: "[asf]", xyz: "5", foo: "b=ar"}
```

## Original answer

A one-liner:

```
JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI("abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5".replace(/&/g, "\",\"").replace(/=/g,"\":\"")) + '"}')
```

Comment: For this to work in CoffeeScript, escape the '=' in the regex.     
.replace(/\=/g,"\":\"")

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe explaining what each portion does would help some people understand it better rather than just copy+paste+hope it works. - let's leave one liners to minifiers :)

Comment: This does not escape the quotes as necessary. Add `.replace(/"/g,'\\"')`

Comment: That's no one-liner... it's a space station.

Comment: better if you use `JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(location.search.substring(1).replace(/&/g, "\",\"").replace(/=/g, "\":\"")) + '"}')`

Comment: What about browsers without JSON.parse() method? Since I have jQuery on my website, If I simply change JSON.parse() to $.parseJSON(), will it work?

Comment: What happens if you have urlencode & in the string? Does not abc=fo%26o&def=%5B%26asf%5D&xyz=5%26 fail?

Comment: The improved solution was what I needed because I used line breaks `%0D%0A` - hexadecimal for 10 (line feed) and 13 (carriage return) - in my email body. Thanks so much!

Comment: This fails if you have an equals sign character in the url to be parsed. EX: "cookie=dlksdlfj=sodkfjhsdlfj"

Comment: Also does not work when you have one of parameters without value.

Comment: Does not handle case 'foo=bar&foo=baz&bim=bat' which I would expect to translate to `{foo: ['bar', 'baz'], bim: 'bat'}`

Comment: There is no standard I know of describing passing arrays in this way. [urlencoded-parsing](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlencoded-parsing) only talks about tuples of key/value pairs.

Comment: This also fails if your result is a `bool` it will convert a `isApproved=false&message=""` to { isApproved: "false", message="" }` which still evaluates to `true`!

Comment: Well, yes. If you want to interpret the query parameters as json types. An equal valid interpretation would be plain english, i.e. isApproved=No

Comment: wait. Which is the most improved? The first one, or the second one?

Comment: The second one. Also the code for the second choice was somewhat garbled (dunno how that happend). I fixed it.

Comment: I think the first solution has the `decodeURI` closing parentheses misplaced. Right now is `decodeURI(search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"')`, and it should be `decodeURI(search.replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"'))`. Also I think that `decodeURIComponent()` works better than `decodeURI()` because it decodes special chars like "@" and "$". So I'd propose: **`decodeURIComponent(search.replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"'))`**. I think it works fine always and avoids the extra complexity of the second solution.

Comment: What about decoding arrays like a[]=1&a[]=2 or eves subarrays like a[0][b]=1&a[0][c]=2

Comment: You could also split() string if you haver the entire location url
```
var search = location.url.split('?')[1];
JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')

```

Comment: doesn't remove the first question's mark in my case, here my URL:  `        Router.replace(`/letchat?name=${this.state.name.replace(" ", "+")}&room=${this.state.room.replace(" ", "+")}`);`

Comment: You have to pass the query part of the URL, which is the part *after* the question mark.

Comment: Doesn't work for `?filters[32][]=2&filters[33][]=9` , any idea?

Comment: What is the point of testing if key is empty string? `return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value)`.  Doesn't it work just as well if you always return `decodeURIComponent(value)`?

Comment: I think SO should discourage this "LATEST YEAR!" thing because the years, keep going by. The best answer is actually the one below 2022.

Comment: @Ziggy, turns out in 2024, there is a one liner, `Object.fromEntries([...new URLSearchParams(params_string).entries()])` or for getting current page params: `Object.fromEntries([...new URLSearchParams(location.search).entries()])`

Answer (score 380):

#### 2023 ES6/7/8 and on approach

Starting ES6 and on, Javascript offers several constructs in order to create a performant solution for this issue.

This includes using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterators)

```js
let params = new URLSearchParams('abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5');
params.get("abc"); // "foo"
```

Should your use case requires you to actually convert it to object, you can implement the following function:

```js
function paramsToObject(entries) {
  const result = {}
  for(const [key, value] of entries) { // each 'entry' is a [key, value] tupple
    result[key] = value;
  }
  return result;
}
```

#### Basic Demo

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams('abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5');
const entries = urlParams.entries(); //returns an iterator of decoded [key,value] tuples
const params = paramsToObject(entries); //{abc:"foo",def:"[asf]",xyz:"5"}
```

#### Using Object.fromEntries and spread

We can use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), replacing `paramsToObject` with `Object.fromEntries(entries)`.

> The value pairs to iterate over are the list name-value pairs with the
> key being the name and the value being the value.

Since `URLParams`, returns an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Iterable_examples) object, using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead of calling `.entries` will also yield entries per its spec:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams('abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5');
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlParams); // {abc: "foo", def: "[asf]", xyz: "5"}
```

**Note:** All values are automatically strings as per the [URLSearchParams spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-urlsearchparams)

#### Multiple same keys

As [@siipe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915496/siipe) pointed out, strings containing multiple same-key values will be coerced into the last available value: `foo=first_value&foo=second_value` will in essence become: `{foo: "second_value"}`.

As per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746566/1194694 there's no spec for deciding what to do with it and each framework can behave differently.

A common use case will be to join the two same values into an array, making the output object into:

```js
{foo: ["first_value", "second_value"]}
```

This can be achieved with the following code:

```js
const groupParamsByKey = (params) => [...params.entries()].reduce((acc, tuple) => {
 // getting the key and value from each tuple
 const [key, val] = tuple;
 if(acc.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // if the current key is already an array, we'll add the value to it
    if(Array.isArray(acc[key])) {
      acc[key] = [...acc[key], val]
    } else {
      // if it's not an array, but contains a value, we'll convert it into an array
      // and add the current value to it
      acc[key] = [acc[key], val];
    }
 } else {
  // plain assignment if no special case is present
  acc[key] = val;
 }

return acc;
}, {});

const params = new URLSearchParams('abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5&def=dude');
const output = groupParamsByKey(params) // {abc: "foo", def: ["[asf]", "dude"], xyz: 5}
```

Comment: I do not recommend this solution.  URLSearchParams has illogical specs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Gotchas)

Comment: I'm sorry but logic doesn't have anything to do with it.
One might argue that it's a `search string` parser - which is what it was designed to do, regardless of it being associated to a URL

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` doesn't work for repeated keys. If we try to do something like `?foo=bar1&foo=bar2`, we'll get only `{ foo: 'bar2' }`. Node.js request object, for example, parses it as `{ foo: ['bar1', 'bar2'] }`

Comment: You're right, however this has no spec and many languages take an opinionated approach as to how they parse it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746566/1194694

Comment: This looks good to me, but to get the values for repetitive key we can use this 
`let temp={};Object.keys(params).map(key=>{temp[key]=urlParams.getAll(key)})`

Comment: It will force every value to be returned in the form of an array which is not good or bad, but worth taking into consideration.

Comment: Using `Object.fromEntries(params)` is required for correct `axios-mock-adapter` integration.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Arrays keys came in the form `foo[]: [1, 2, 3]` but I wanted `foo: [1, 2, 3]` so I added one extra line:
```
const [ _key, val ] = tuple
const key = _key.replace(/\[]$/, '')
```

Answer (score 371):

**One liner. Clean and simple.**

```
const params = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(location.search));
```

For your specific case, it would be:

```js
const str = 'abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5';
const params = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(str));
console.log(params);
```

Comment: This can be used, but with caution `?someValue=false` becomes `{ someValue: "false" }`

Comment: It doesn't work for repeated keys. If we try to do something like `?foo=bar1&foo=bar2`, we'll get only `{ foo: 'bar2' }`.
Node.js request object parses it as `{ foo: ['bar1', 'bar2'] }`

Comment: this fails with arrays, ex: x=1&x=2 -> result {x:2}

Comment: calling `getQuery( )` breaks JavaScript execution in `<body><script> /**/ alert('Win 10 & Android 10'); /**/ const getQuery = ( ) => Object.fromEntries( new URLSearchParams( location.search ).entries( ) ); /**/ const query = getQuery( ); /**/ alert('No Android 10'); /**/ </script></body>`

Comment: @simon so does `new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("someValue")` which is the usual methd

Answer (score 80):

**2023 One-Liner Approach**

For the general case where you want to parse query params to an object:

```
Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(location.search));
```

For your specific case:

```
Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams('abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5'));
```

Comment: Also `[...new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)].reduce((o, i) => ({ ...o, [i[0]]: i[1] }), {});`

Comment: Note that this converts `?booleanValue=true` to `{ booleanValue: "true" }` which may be undesirable.

Comment: This is a BAD solution when you have an array field within your query params. In a case where you have ids=1&ids=2, you'd get back { ids: '2' }.

Answer (score 35):

Split on `&` to get name/value pairs, then split each pair on `=`. Here's an example:

```
var str = "abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xy%5Bz=5"
var obj = str.split("&").reduce(function(prev, curr, i, arr) {
    var p = curr.split("=");
    prev[decodeURIComponent(p[0])] = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
    return prev;
}, {});
```

Another approach, using regular expressions:

```
var obj = {}; 
str.replace(/([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g, function(m, key, value) {
    obj[decodeURIComponent(key)] = decodeURIComponent(value);
});
```

This is adapted from John Resig's ["Search and Don’t Replace"](http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/).

Comment: tx! you should also add decodeURIComponen(p[0]) in the left :)

Comment: The first example doesn't work with an empty query string.

Answer (score 29):

The proposed solutions I found so far do not cover more complex scenarios.

I needed to convert a query string like

`https://random.url.com?Target=Offer&Method=findAll&filters%5Bhas_goals_enabled%5D%5BTRUE%5D=1&filters%5Bstatus%5D=active&fields%5B%5D=id&fields%5B%5D=name&fields%5B%5D=default_goal_name`

into an object like:

```
{
    "Target": "Offer",
    "Method": "findAll",
    "fields": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "default_goal_name"
    ],
    "filters": {
        "has_goals_enabled": {
            "TRUE": "1"
        },
        "status": "active"
    }
}
```

OR:

`https://random.url.com?Target=Report&Method=getStats&fields%5B%5D=Offer.name&fields%5B%5D=Advertiser.company&fields%5B%5D=Stat.clicks&fields%5B%5D=Stat.conversions&fields%5B%5D=Stat.cpa&fields%5B%5D=Stat.payout&fields%5B%5D=Stat.date&fields%5B%5D=Stat.offer_id&fields%5B%5D=Affiliate.company&groups%5B%5D=Stat.offer_id&groups%5B%5D=Stat.date&filters%5BStat.affiliate_id%5D%5Bconditional%5D=EQUAL_TO&filters%5BStat.affiliate_id%5D%5Bvalues%5D=1831&limit=9999`

INTO:

```
{
    "Target": "Report",
    "Method": "getStats",
    "fields": [
        "Offer.name",
        "Advertiser.company",
        "Stat.clicks",
        "Stat.conversions",
        "Stat.cpa",
        "Stat.payout",
        "Stat.date",
        "Stat.offer_id",
        "Affiliate.company"
    ],
    "groups": [
        "Stat.offer_id",
        "Stat.date"
    ],
    "limit": "9999",
    "filters": {
        "Stat.affiliate_id": {
            "conditional": "EQUAL_TO",
            "values": "1831"
        }
    }
}
```

### I compiled and adapted multiple solutions into one that actually works:

CODE:

```
var getParamsAsObject = function (query) {

    query = query.substring(query.indexOf('?') + 1);

    var re = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;
    var decodeRE = /\+/g;

    var decode = function (str) {
        return decodeURIComponent(str.replace(decodeRE, " "));
    };

    var params = {}, e;
    while (e = re.exec(query)) {
        var k = decode(e[1]), v = decode(e[2]);
        if (k.substring(k.length - 2) === '[]') {
            k = k.substring(0, k.length - 2);
            (params[k] || (params[k] = [])).push(v);
        }
        else params[k] = v;
    }

    var assign = function (obj, keyPath, value) {
        var lastKeyIndex = keyPath.length - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < lastKeyIndex; ++i) {
            var key = keyPath[i];
            if (!(key in obj))
                obj[key] = {}
            obj = obj[key];
        }
        obj[keyPath[lastKeyIndex]] = value;
    }

    for (var prop in params) {
        var structure = prop.split('[');
        if (structure.length > 1) {
            var levels = [];
            structure.forEach(function (item, i) {
                var key = item.replace(/[?[\]\\ ]/g, '');
                levels.push(key);
            });
            assign(params, levels, params[prop]);
            delete(params[prop]);
        }
    }
    return params;
};
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as it is indeed properly handles complex queries.

Comment: I think this just complicates things, I'd just pass `obj=encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({what:{ever:','},i:['like']}))`.

Comment: Now this is what I'm talking about. The most complete answer I could find here!

Answer (score 22):

A concise solution:

```
location.search
  .slice(1)
  .split('&')
  .map(p => p.split('='))
  .reduce((obj, pair) => {
    const [key, value] = pair.map(decodeURIComponent);
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
```

Comment: this fails with arrays i.e: x=1&x=2

Comment: Thanks. Working fine for ?test&withval=1

{test: undefined, withval: 1}

Answer (score 18):

This is the simple version, obviously you'll want to add some error checking:

```
var obj = {};
var pairs = queryString.split('&');
for(i in pairs){
    var split = pairs[i].split('=');
    obj[decodeURIComponent(split[0])] = decodeURIComponent(split[1]);
}
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to unencode the string to convert the %5B and %5D to characters?

Comment: @Alex - Did you use the updated code or the original? Original had one issue and a typo.

Comment: It can't handle params properly when their values contain '='.  It trims the values to first '='.

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURIComponent(query.replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}'));` works for me

Comment: its doesnt work for `name[]=test1&name[]=test2` and it will result in `name[]=test2`

Comment: To handle parameters with a second '=' character, replace `split[1]` by `split.slice(1).join("=")`

Answer (score 12):

For Node JS, you can use the Node JS API `querystring`:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

querystring.parse('abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5&foo=b%3Dar');
// returns the object
```

Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

Answer (score 10):

I found [$.String.deparam](https://github.com/jupiterjs/jquerymx/blob/master/lang/string/deparam/deparam.js) the most complete pre built solution (can do nested objects etc.). Check out the [documentation](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.String.deparam).

Comment: just pointing out if your input is always going to be a serialized query string there is no need to worry about nesting and a more lightweight solution is probably better

Comment: Well of course... but it's been done and tested already (Justin e.g. forget to URI decode in the initial answer - which are small issues that can make things a lot more complex than they initially seem).

Answer (score 9):

Another solution based on the latest standard of URLSearchParams (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
function getQueryParamsObject() {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search.slice(1));
  return searchParams
    ? _.fromPairs(Array.from(searchParams.entries()))
    : {};
}
```

Please note that this solution is making use of

**Array.from** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

and **_.fromPairs** (https://lodash.com/docs#fromPairs) of lodash for the sake of simplicity.

It should be easy to create a more compatible solution since you have access to *searchParams.entries()* iterator.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, tried the solutions here, but none of them really worked, since I had arrays in the URL parameters, like this:

```
?param[]=5&param[]=8&othr_param=abc&param[]=string
```

So I ended up writing my own JS function, which makes an array out of the param in URI:

```
/**
 * Creates an object from URL encoded data
 */
var createObjFromURI = function() {
    var uri = decodeURI(location.search.substr(1));
    var chunks = uri.split('&');
    var params = Object();

    for (var i=0; i < chunks.length ; i++) {
        var chunk = chunks[i].split('=');
        if(chunk[0].search("\\[\\]") !== -1) {
            if( typeof params[chunk[0]] === 'undefined' ) {
                params[chunk[0]] = [chunk[1]];

            } else {
                params[chunk[0]].push(chunk[1]);
            }


        } else {
            params[chunk[0]] = chunk[1];
        }
    }

    return params;
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful and did almost exactly what I wanted.  I didn't like, though, how the "[]" is kept in tact in the object if the URL parameters are like: bacon[]=eggs&bacon[]=toast.  So I added in a line after `if(chunk[0].search("\\[\\]") !== -1) {` that is `chunk[0]=chunk[0].replace(/\[\]$/,'');`

Comment: @rgbflawed you should edit the answer for the sake of future reader and legibility

Comment: Use `const` instead of `var` because someone might do `createObjFromURI = 'some text'` and then they would mess up the code. if you use `const` then someone running `createObjFromURI = 'some text'` will make an error cannot assign value to constant variable.

Answer (score 7):

There is quite simple and incorrect answer with ES6:

```js
console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(`abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5`))
);
```

But this one line code do not cover **multiple same keys**, you have to use something more complicated:

```js
function parseParams(params) {
  const output = [];
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

  // Set will return only unique keys()
  new Set([...searchParams.keys()])
    .forEach(key => {
      output[key] = searchParams.getAll(key).length > 1 ?  
        searchParams.getAll(key) : // get multiple values
        searchParams.get(key); // get single value
    });

  return output;
}

console.log(
   parseParams('abc=foo&cars=Ford&cars=BMW&cars=Skoda&cars=Mercedes')
)
```

Code will generate follow structure:

```
[
  abc: "foo"
  cars: ["Ford", "BMW", "Skoda", "Mercedes"]
]
```

Comment: Best answer from all of these

Answer (score 6):

Pretty easy using the `URLSearchParams` JavaScript Web API,

```js
var paramsString = "abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5";

//returns an iterator object
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

//Usage
for (let p of searchParams) {
  console.log(p);
}

//Get the query strings
console.log(searchParams.toString());

//You can also pass in objects

var paramsObject = {abc:"forum",def:"%5Basf%5D",xyz:"5"}

//returns an iterator object
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsObject);

//Usage
for (let p of searchParams) {
  console.log(p);
}

//Get the query strings
console.log(searchParams.toString());
```

##Useful Links

- [URLSearchParams - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)
- [Easy URL Manipulation with URLSearchParams  |  Web
  | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams?hl=en)

> **NOTE**: *Not Supported in IE*

Answer (score 6):

ES6 one liner (if we can call it that way seeing the long line)

`[...new URLSearchParams(location.search).entries()].reduce((prev, [key,val]) => {prev[key] = val; return prev}, {})`

Comment: You can also destructure the `cur` for some added clarity. `.reduce((prev, [key, val]) => {prev[key] = val})`

Comment: i like your suggestion Allan Lei. I update my answer

Answer (score 6):

One of the simplest way to do this using URLSearchParam interface.

Below is the working code snippet:

```
let paramObj={},
    querystring=window.location.search,
    searchParams = new URLSearchParams(querystring);    

  //*** :loop to add key and values to the param object.
 searchParams.forEach(function(value, key) {
      paramObj[key] = value;
   });
```

Answer (score 5):

Using ES6, URL API and URLSearchParams API.

```
function objectifyQueryString(url) {
  let _url = new URL(url);
  let _params = new URLSearchParams(_url.search);
  let query = Array.from(_params.keys()).reduce((sum, value)=>{
    return Object.assign({[value]: _params.get(value)}, sum);
  }, {});
  return query;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One simple answer with build in native Node module.(No third party npm modules)

The querystring module provides utilities for parsing and formatting URL query strings. It can be accessed using:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

const body = "abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5"
const parseJSON = querystring.parse(body);
console.log(parseJSON);
```

Comment: Nice. I have tried this and it's working in Angular, i'm using `import * as querystring from "querystring";`

Comment: This is also available in the browser in any npm package with the same name and functionality (`npm install querystring`)

Answer (score 4):

There is no native solution that I'm aware of. Dojo has a built-in unserialization method if you use that framework by chance.

Otherwise you can implement it yourself rather simply:

```
function unserialize(str) {
  str = decodeURIComponent(str);
  var chunks = str.split('&'),
      obj = {};
  for(var c=0; c < chunks.length; c++) {
    var split = chunks[c].split('=', 2);
    obj[split[0]] = split[1];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

edit: added decodeURIComponent()

Answer (score 3):

```js
console.log(decodeURI('abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5')
  .split('&')
  .reduce((result, current) => {
    const [key, value] = current.split('=');

    result[key] = value;

    return result
  }, {}))
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
/**
 * Parses and builds Object of URL query string.
 * @param {string} query The URL query string.
 * @return {!Object<string, string>}
 */
function parseQueryString(query) {
  if (!query) {
    return {};
  }
  return (/^[?#]/.test(query) ? query.slice(1) : query)
      .split('&')
      .reduce((params, param) => {
        const item = param.split('=');
        const key = decodeURIComponent(item[0] || '');
        const value = decodeURIComponent(item[1] || '');
        if (key) {
          params[key] = value;
        }
        return params;
      }, {});
}

console.log(parseQueryString('?v=MFa9pvnVe0w&ku=user&from=89&aw=1'))
```

```html
see log
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a lightweight library called [YouAreI.js](https://github.com/purge/youarei.js) that's tested and makes this really easy.

```
YouAreI = require('YouAreI')
uri = new YouAreI('http://user:pass@www.example.com:3000/a/b/c?d=dad&e=1&f=12.3#fragment');

uri.query_get() => { d: 'dad', e: '1', f: '12.3' }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using URI.js, you can use:

https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#static-parseQuery

```
var result = URI.parseQuery("?foo=bar&hello=world&hello=mars&bam=&yup");
result === {
  foo: "bar",
  hello: ["world", "mars"],
  bam: "",
  yup: null
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the best solution as it takes multiple parameters of the same name into consideration.

```
    function paramsToJSON(str) {
        var pairs = str.split('&');
        var result = {};
        pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
            pair = pair.split('=');
            var name = pair[0]
            var value = pair[1]
            if( name.length )
                if (result[name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!result[name].push) {
                        result[name] = [result[name]];
                    }
                    result[name].push(value || '');
                } else {
                    result[name] = value || '';
                }
        });
        return( result );
    }

<a href="index.html?x=1&x=2&x=3&y=blah">something</a>
paramsToJSON("x=1&x=2&x=3&y=blah"); 

console yields => {x: Array[3], y: "blah"} where x is an array as is proper JSON
```

I later decided to convert it to a jQuery plugin too...

```
$.fn.serializeURLParams = function() {
    var result = {};

    if( !this.is("a") || this.attr("href").indexOf("?") == -1 ) 
        return( result );

    var pairs = this.attr("href").split("?")[1].split('&');
    pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
        pair = pair.split('=');
        var name = decodeURI(pair[0])
        var value = decodeURI(pair[1])
        if( name.length )
            if (result[name] !== undefined) {
                if (!result[name].push) {
                    result[name] = [result[name]];
                }
                result[name].push(value || '');
            } else {
                result[name] = value || '';
            }
    });
    return( result )
}

<a href="index.html?x=1&x=2&x=3&y=blah">something</a>
$("a").serializeURLParams(); 

console yields => {x: Array[3], y: "blah"} where x is an array as is proper JSON
```

Now, the first will accept the parameters only but the jQuery plugin will take the whole url and return the serialized parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one I use:

```
var params = {};
window.location.search.substring(1).split('&').forEach(function(pair) {
  pair = pair.split('=');
  if (pair[1] !== undefined) {
    var key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]),
        val = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]),
        val = val ? val.replace(/\++/g,' ').trim() : '';

    if (key.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    if (params[key] === undefined) {
      params[key] = val;
    }
    else {
      if ("function" !== typeof params[key].push) {
        params[key] = [params[key]];
      }
      params[key].push(val);
    }
  }
});
console.log(params);
```

Basic usage, eg.
`?a=aa&b=bb`
`Object {a: "aa", b: "bb"}`

Duplicate params, eg.
`?a=aa&b=bb&c=cc&c=potato`
`Object {a: "aa", b: "bb", c: ["cc","potato"]}`

Missing keys, eg.
`?a=aa&b=bb&=cc`
`Object {a: "aa", b: "bb"}`

Missing values, eg.
`?a=aa&b=bb&c`
`Object {a: "aa", b: "bb"}`

The above JSON/regex solutions throw a syntax error on this wacky url:
`?a=aa&b=bb&c=&=dd&e`
`Object {a: "aa", b: "bb", c: ""}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my quick and dirty version, basically its splitting up the URL parameters separated by '&' into array elements, and then iterates over that array adding key/value pairs separated by '=' into an object. I'm using decodeURIComponent() to translate the encoded characters to their normal string equivalents (so %20 becomes a space, %26 becomes '&', etc):

```
function deparam(paramStr) {
    let paramArr = paramStr.split('&');     
    let paramObj = {};
    paramArr.forEach(e=>{
        let param = e.split('=');
        paramObj[param[0]] = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
    });
    return paramObj;
}
```

example:

```
deparam('abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5')
```

returns

```
{
    abc: "foo"
    def:"[asf]"
    xyz :"5"
}
```

The only issue is that xyz is a string and not a number (due to using decodeURIComponent()), but beyond that its not a bad starting point.

Answer (score 1):

```
//under ES6 
const getUrlParamAsObject = (url = window.location.href) => {
    let searchParams = url.split('?')[1];
    const result = {};
    //in case the queryString is empty
    if (searchParams!==undefined) {
        const paramParts = searchParams.split('&');
        for(let part of paramParts) {
            let paramValuePair = part.split('=');
            //exclude the case when the param has no value
            if(paramValuePair.length===2) {
                result[paramValuePair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(paramValuePair[1]);
            }
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I really like this method (in 2017) compared to some of the other regex-based answers. If polyfill the arrow function (or rewrite as a traditional function), I think this should work pretty well cross-browser

Comment: @Scribblemacher with `Babel`'s help you can do it well under other environment

Answer (score 1):

If you need recursion, you can use the tiny **js-extension-ling** library.

```sh
npm i js-extension-ling
```

```js
const jsx = require("js-extension-ling");

console.log(jsx.queryStringToObject("a=1")); 
console.log(jsx.queryStringToObject("a=1&a=3")); 
console.log(jsx.queryStringToObject("a[]=1")); 
console.log(jsx.queryStringToObject("a[]=1&a[]=pomme")); 
console.log(jsx.queryStringToObject("a[0]=one&a[1]=five"));
console.log(jsx.queryStringToObject("http://blabla?foo=bar&number=1234")); 
console.log(jsx.queryStringToObject("a[fruits][red][]=strawberry"));
console.log(jsx.queryStringToObject("a[fruits][red][]=strawberry&a[1]=five&a[fruits][red][]=cherry&a[fruits][yellow][]=lemon&a[fruits][yellow][688]=banana"));
```

This will output something like this:

```sh
{ a: '1' }
{ a: '3' }
{ a: { '0': '1' } }
{ a: { '0': '1', '1': 'pomme' } }
{ a: { '0': 'one', '1': 'five' } }
{ foo: 'bar', number: '1234' }
{
  a: { fruits: { red: { '0': 'strawberry' } } }
}
{
  a: {
    '1': 'five',
    fruits: {
      red: { '0': 'strawberry', '1': 'cherry' },
      yellow: { '0': 'lemon', '688': 'banana' }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: it's based on locutus parse_str function (https://locutus.io/php/strings/parse_str/).

Answer (score 0):

FIRST U NEED TO DEFINE WHAT'S A GET VAR:

```
function getVar()
{
    this.length = 0;
    this.keys = [];
    this.push = function(key, value)
    {
        if(key=="") key = this.length++;
        this[key] = value;
        this.keys.push(key);
        return this[key];
    }
}
```

Than just read:

```
function urlElement()
{
    var thisPrototype = window.location;
    for(var prototypeI in thisPrototype) this[prototypeI] = thisPrototype[prototypeI];
    this.Variables = new getVar();
    if(!this.search) return this;
    var variables = this.search.replace(/\?/g,'').split('&');
    for(var varI=0; varI<variables.length; varI++)
    {
        var nameval = variables[varI].split('=');
        var name = nameval[0].replace(/\]/g,'').split('[');
        var pVariable = this.Variables;
        for(var nameI=0;nameI<name.length;nameI++)
        {
            if(name.length-1==nameI) pVariable.push(name[nameI],nameval[1]);
            else var pVariable = (typeof pVariable[name[nameI]] != 'object')? pVariable.push(name[nameI],new getVar()) : pVariable[name[nameI]];
        }
    }
}
```

and use like:

```
var mlocation = new urlElement();
mlocation = mlocation.Variables;
for(var key=0;key<mlocation.keys.length;key++)
{
    console.log(key);
    console.log(mlocation[mlocation.keys[key]];
}
```

Comment: Please merge your answers. [Edit the other one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13366851/edit), then delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to also deal with `+` in the query part of the URL ([decodeURIComponent doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535288/why-doesnt-decodeuriab-a-b)), so I adapted Wolfgang's code to become:

```
var search = location.search.substring(1);
search = search?JSON.parse('{"' + search.replace(/\+/g, ' ').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}',
             function(key, value) { return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value)}):{};
```

In my case, I'm using jQuery to get URL-ready form parameters, then this trick to build an object out of it and I can then easily update parameters on the object and rebuild the query URL, e.g.:

```
var objForm = JSON.parse('{"' + $myForm.serialize().replace(/\+/g, ' ').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}',
             function(key, value) { return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value)});
objForm.anyParam += stringToAddToTheParam;
var serializedForm = $.param(objForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using phpjs

```
function parse_str(str, array) {
  //       discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_str/
  //      original by: Cagri Ekin
  //      improved by: Michael White (http://getsprink.com)
  //      improved by: Jack
  //      improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //      bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  //      bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //      bugfixed by: stag019
  //      bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //      bugfixed by: MIO_KODUKI (http://mio-koduki.blogspot.com/)
  // reimplemented by: stag019
  //         input by: Dreamer
  //         input by: Zaide (http://zaidesthings.com/)
  //         input by: David Pesta (http://davidpesta.com/)
  //         input by: jeicquest
  //             note: When no argument is specified, will put variables in global scope.
  //             note: When a particular argument has been passed, and the returned value is different parse_str of PHP. For example, a=b=c&d====c
  //             test: skip
  //        example 1: var arr = {};
  //        example 1: parse_str('first=foo&second=bar', arr);
  //        example 1: $result = arr
  //        returns 1: { first: 'foo', second: 'bar' }
  //        example 2: var arr = {};
  //        example 2: parse_str('str_a=Jack+and+Jill+didn%27t+see+the+well.', arr);
  //        example 2: $result = arr
  //        returns 2: { str_a: "Jack and Jill didn't see the well." }
  //        example 3: var abc = {3:'a'};
  //        example 3: parse_str('abc[a][b]["c"]=def&abc[q]=t+5');
  //        returns 3: {"3":"a","a":{"b":{"c":"def"}},"q":"t 5"}

  var strArr = String(str)
    .replace(/^&/, '')
    .replace(/&$/, '')
    .split('&'),
    sal = strArr.length,
    i, j, ct, p, lastObj, obj, lastIter, undef, chr, tmp, key, value,
    postLeftBracketPos, keys, keysLen,
    fixStr = function(str) {
      return decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
    };

  if (!array) {
    array = this.window;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < sal; i++) {
    tmp = strArr[i].split('=');
    key = fixStr(tmp[0]);
    value = (tmp.length < 2) ? '' : fixStr(tmp[1]);

    while (key.charAt(0) === ' ') {
      key = key.slice(1);
    }
    if (key.indexOf('\x00') > -1) {
      key = key.slice(0, key.indexOf('\x00'));
    }
    if (key && key.charAt(0) !== '[') {
      keys = [];
      postLeftBracketPos = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < key.length; j++) {
        if (key.charAt(j) === '[' && !postLeftBracketPos) {
          postLeftBracketPos = j + 1;
        } else if (key.charAt(j) === ']') {
          if (postLeftBracketPos) {
            if (!keys.length) {
              keys.push(key.slice(0, postLeftBracketPos - 1));
            }
            keys.push(key.substr(postLeftBracketPos, j - postLeftBracketPos));
            postLeftBracketPos = 0;
            if (key.charAt(j + 1) !== '[') {
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (!keys.length) {
        keys = [key];
      }
      for (j = 0; j < keys[0].length; j++) {
        chr = keys[0].charAt(j);
        if (chr === ' ' || chr === '.' || chr === '[') {
          keys[0] = keys[0].substr(0, j) + '_' + keys[0].substr(j + 1);
        }
        if (chr === '[') {
          break;
        }
      }

      obj = array;
      for (j = 0, keysLen = keys.length; j < keysLen; j++) {
        key = keys[j].replace(/^['"]/, '')
          .replace(/['"]$/, '');
        lastIter = j !== keys.length - 1;
        lastObj = obj;
        if ((key !== '' && key !== ' ') || j === 0) {
          if (obj[key] === undef) {
            obj[key] = {};
          }
          obj = obj[key];
        } else { // To insert new dimension
          ct = -1;
          for (p in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
              if (+p > ct && p.match(/^\d+$/g)) {
                ct = +p;
              }
            }
          }
          key = ct + 1;
        }
      }
      lastObj[key] = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of [Mike Causer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28554494/2272346) I've made this function which takes into consideration multiple params with the same key (`foo=bar&foo=baz`) and also comma-separated parameters (`foo=bar,baz,bin`). It also lets you search for a certain query key.

```
function getQueryParams(queryKey) {
    var queryString = window.location.search;
    var query = {};
    var pairs = (queryString[0] === '?' ? queryString.substr(1) : queryString).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
        var key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
        var value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
        // Se possui uma vírgula no valor, converter em um array
        value = (value.indexOf(',') === -1 ? value : value.split(','));

        // Se a key já existe, tratar ela como um array
        if (query[key]) {
            if (query[key].constructor === Array) {
                // Array.concat() faz merge se o valor inserido for um array
                query[key] = query[key].concat(value);
            } else {
                // Se não for um array, criar um array contendo o valor anterior e o novo valor
                query[key] = [query[key], value];
            }
        } else {
            query[key] = value;
        }
    }

    if (typeof queryKey === 'undefined') {
        return query;
    } else {
        return query[queryKey];
    }
}
```

Example input:
`foo.html?foo=bar&foo=baz&foo=bez,boz,buz&bar=1,2,3`

Example output

```
{
    foo: ["bar","baz","bez","boz","buz"],
    bar: ["1","2","3"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more-streamlined version of [silicakes' approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52539264/1762224).

The following function(s) can parse a querystring from either a [`USVString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString) or [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

```js
/**
 * Returns a plain object representation of a URLSearchParams object.
 * @param {USVString} search - A URL querystring
 * @return {Object} a key-value pair object from a URL querystring
 */
const parseSearch = (search) =>
  [...new URLSearchParams(search).entries()]
    .reduce((acc, [key, val]) => ({
      ...acc,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-nested-ternary
      [key]: Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(acc, key)
        ? Array.isArray(acc[key])
          ? [...acc[key], val]
          : [acc[key], val]
        : val
    }), {});

/**
 * Returns a plain object representation of a URLSearchParams object.
 * @param {Location} location - Either a document or window location, or React useLocation()
 * @return {Object} a key-value pair object from a URL querystring
 */
const parseLocationSearch = (location) => parseSearch(location.search);

console.log(parseSearch('?foo=bar&x=y&ids=%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D&ids=%5B4%2C5%2C6%5D'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is a one-liner of the code above (125 bytes):

> *Where `f` is `parseSearch`*

```js
f=s=>[...new URLSearchParams(s).entries()].reduce((a,[k,v])=>({...a,[k]:a[k]?Array.isArray(a[k])?[...a[k],v]:[a[k],v]:v}),{})
```

---

### Edit

Here is a method of serializing and updating:

```js
const parseSearch = (search) =>
  [...new URLSearchParams(search).entries()]
    .reduce((acc, [key, val]) => ({
      ...acc,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-nested-ternary
      [key]: Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(acc, key)
        ? Array.isArray(acc[key])
          ? [...acc[key], val]
          : [acc[key], val]
        : val
    }), {});

const toQueryString = (params) =>
  `?${Object.entries(params)
    .flatMap(([key, values]) =>
      Array.isArray(values)
        ? values.map(value => [key, value])
        : [[key, values]])
    .map(pair => pair.map(val => encodeURIComponent(val)).join('='))
    .join('&')}`;

const updateQueryString = (search, update) =>
  (parsed =>
    toQueryString(update instanceof Function
      ? update(parsed)
      : { ...parsed, ...update }))
  (parseSearch(search));

const queryString = '?foo=bar&x=y&ids=%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D&ids=%5B4%2C5%2C6%5D';
const parsedQuery = parseSearch(queryString);
console.log(parsedQuery);
console.log(toQueryString(parsedQuery) === queryString);

const updatedQuerySimple = updateQueryString(queryString, {
  foo: 'baz',
  x: 'z',
});
console.log(updatedQuerySimple);
console.log(parseSearch(updatedQuerySimple));

const updatedQuery = updateQueryString(updatedQuerySimple, parsed => ({
  ...parsed,
  ids: [
    ...parsed.ids,
    JSON.stringify([7,8,9])
  ]
}));
console.log(updatedQuery);
console.log(parseSearch(updatedQuery));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Many other solutions don't account for edge cases.

This one handles

- null keys `a=1&b=2&`
- null values `a=1&b`
- empty values `a=1&b=`
- unencoded equals signs `a=1&b=2=3=4`

```js
  decodeQueryString: qs => {
    // expects qs to not have a ?
    // return if empty qs
    if (qs === '') return {};
    return qs.split('&').reduce((acc, pair) => {
      // skip no param at all a=1&b=2&
      if (pair.length === 0) return acc;
      const parts = pair.split('=');
      // fix params without value
      if (parts.length === 1) parts[1] = '';
      // for value handle multiple unencoded = signs
      const key = decodeURIComponent(parts[0]);
      const value = decodeURIComponent(parts.slice(1).join('='));
      acc[key] = value;
      return acc;
    }, {});
  },
```