# Javascript / jQuery URL Query Params Parse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, parameters

I have a URL query that looks like this:

`view-mode=grid&filters%5Bone%5D%3D1%26filters%5Btwo%5D%3D2`

Ultimately I want to be able to parse the parameters in both PHP and Javascripting (using jQuery). No issues parsing in PHP using $_GET. Trying to figure out how to do it using Javascript. The final object in Javascript should look like this:

`{
  "view-mode" : "grid",
  "filters" : {
    "one" : "1",
    "two" : "2"
  }
}`

Any suggestions? I am using [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html) for some building and parsing already.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert URL parameters to a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I've tried that solution, but the result is `{filters[one]: "1", filters[two]: "2"}`

Comment: Where is this data coming from? Are you generating it yourself? Can you json encode the object and pass it, instead of however it is being passed now?

Comment: It's coming from a URL. I think I figured it out. Testing now... Looks like I can use the BBQ plugin to deparam the querystring. http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html#jQuery.deparam.querystring

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

I used [URL.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html) to get the query parameters using
`URI(location.href).query(true)`

I get an object with a few properties, including "***view-mode***" and "***filters[one]=1&filters[two]=2***" where "***filters[one]=1&filters[two]=2***" is an object (based on the way URL.js parses the query).

Then I iterate through the object and check if the property is an object. If it is, I use [Ben Alman's BBQ jQuery Plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html#jQuery.deparam.querystring) to parse the property name which turns:

`filters%5Bone%5D%3D1%26filters%5Btwo%5D%3D2`

into:

`{
  "filters" : {
    "one" : "1",
    "two" : "2"
  }
}`

*The URI.js parsing method also results in a few properties that have no value such as "***filters[one]=1&filters[two]=2[1](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html)***" and "***filters[one]=1&filters[two]=2[]***". I ignore those.*

Then I can combine the original properties that aren't objects such as "***view-mode=grid***" with the parsed properties that are objects, such as "***filters%5Bone%5D%3D1%26filters%5Btwo%5D%3D2***" and I end up with:

`{
  "view-mode" : "grid",
  "filters" : {
    "one" : "1",
    "two" : "2"
  }
}`

End result is that both Javascript and PHP can read and understand the query parameters.