# Decode parameters of URL to an object with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, object, url

Is there an easier/shorte/AngularJS way to make the conversion of
parameters from URL to a JavaScript object shorter than

```
JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')
```

(the answer above pulled from [SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object)

What needs to be done is to convert a long string with many parameters such as

```
field1=value1&field2=value2...
```

into an object

Object `{field1: "value1",field2: "value2",...}`

Comment: both the angular router and the 3rd party ui-router automatically convert URL parameters to individual objects, and the `$location` service also can expose URL parameters.  can you show the code that you are currently using, including any router, if applicable?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I can't share more code. It's not in the current URL.  It's a variable that is a string.

Comment: why do you have a variable that is an HTML parameter list?  That isn't a normal angular practice...

Comment: also, since the code you posted *technically works*, and you aren't willing/able to post any more code illustrating why this isn't suitable, it's very difficult to make suggestions about better alternatives, and it's questionable if this is even useful to others in the future.