# How to update serialized Cookie Value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cookies, serialization

Hi I have cookie which has value of serialized params.

```
i.e)criteria = "name=praveen&age=25&studying=false&working=true&something=value"
```

Now I have to update  name = praveenkumar,age = 24,something = null in this cookie string. If value is null(something = null) then it should be removed from cookie. The following is the code I am using.

```
updateCookie({'name':'praveenkumar','age':24,'something':null})
var updateCookie = function(params) {
// split the cookie into array
var arr = $.cookie('criteria').split("&");
//loop through each element
for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  // getting the key i.e) name,age
  var key = arr[i].split("=")[0];
  // if the key is in given param updating the value
  if( key in params) {
    // if vale null remove the element from array or update the value
    if(params[key] !== null) {
      arr[i] = key+"="+params[key];
    }
    else {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
// join array by & to frame cookie string again
$.cookie('criteria' , arr.join("&"));
```

};

It is working. But I am concerned about performance if the size of cookie become more.

Answer (score 0):

Way too complicated. Try this instead :

```js
var criteria = "name=praveen&age=25&studying=false&working=true&something=value";
```

Turn the serialized string into a object

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(criteria)
                           .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
                           .replace(/&/g, '","')
                           .replace(/=/g,'":"') 
                  + '"}')
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649003/1407478). Now you can manipulate the object

```js
obj.studying = null;
```

Remove `null` values from the object

```js
for (prop in obj) {
  if (obj[prop] == null) delete obj[prop]
}
```

use jQuery's `$.param` to get the modified object as serialized string

```js
criteria = $.param(obj);
```

== `name=praveen&age=25&working=true&something=value`

save the updated cookie value

```js
$.cookie('criteria', criteria);
```

---

I do not understand the concern about performance, You should never expect a browser to allow more than 4096 bytes in a cookie. If performance and size is a concern you should use localStorage. It is much faster than cookies and has capacity measured in MB's (vary from browser to browser).

Comment: @davidkonard It was really helpfull. The performance thing is number of parameter stored in cookie may increase, enumerating through each param may cost more.