# convert serialized form to individual post items

Tags: javascript, jquery

how would i go about converting a serialized form into individual post items? It is a dynamic form and I will never know exactly what the fields will be.

I am trying to convert it to an array and then loop thorugh and build the $.post that way but its failing to do it, this is what i have at the moment.

```
  var data = $('#report_manager_frame_report #reportForm').serialize();
  //var data example:
  //"hotelid=7696&date=2016-03-01&exportSelect=HTML4.0&parameters=&exportName=&reportName=%2Fwelcome_reports%2FDaily+Revenue+Report&reportName=&hotelid=7696&date=&exportSelect=HTML4.0&parameters=false&exportName=&reportName=%2Fwelcome_reports%2FDaily+Revenue+Report&hotelid=7696&date=&exportSelect=HTML4.0&parameters=false&exportName=&reportName=%2Fwelcome_reports%2FDaily+Revenue+Report"
  var data_split = data.split('&');
  var data_count = data_split.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < data_count; i++) {
    var values = data_split[i].split('=');
    var datavals =+ "'"+values[0]+"':'"+values[1]+"'";
  }
   $.post('c/lib/ssrs/GetReports.php',{datavals})
   .done(function(data){
     $('#report_manager_frame_report').html(data);
   })
```

the output i need is `$.post('LINK',{key:name,key:name,key:name})`
Thanks for any help anyone can offer

Comment: Why is `datavals` in `{}`?

Comment: Try this: `var datavals = {}; for(... { var values = ... ; datavals[values[0]] = values[1]; }`

Comment: Do you want to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object ?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas yes, that's what I think I need! :)

Comment: @freedomn-m yes i think i've done a duplicate :/