# How to convert string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string:

```
ROZ=misparey_batim&CL=rechovot
```

I need to convert this string:

```
"{ROZ:'misparey_batim', CL:'rechovot'}"
```

How can I convert it using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var inputstring = "ROZ=misparey_batim&CL=rechovot";
console.log(JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(inputstring).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}'));
```

Comment: This answer is just copied from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object

Comment: You can't say copied because thats the way. i have already marked it  duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach:

```
const keyVals = string.split('&');
const results = {};
keyVals.forEach(kv => {
   kv = kv.split('=');
   results[kv[0]] = kv[1];
});
```

But personally I'd just search for a query string parser [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)