# URL Param: Line break %0A causing JSON.parse to choke

Tags: javascript, json, regex, urlencode

I am parsing a multiline value from a textarea encoded in the URL:

```
// URL Params:
?cn=asdf%20asdf&pn=asdf%20asdf&pe=asdf%40example.com&d=asdf%0A%0Aasdf&ye=test%40example.com&c=1234&tc=true

// JAVASCRIPT
var _url = window.location.href;
var _queryParams = decodeURIComponent( _url.split('?')[1] );
var _search = _queryParams;//location.search.substring(1);
var _data = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(_search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}');
```

But I'm getting an `Syntax Error: Unexpected token...` error from the `JSON.parse()` function whenever I have a multiline text value in the `d=` URL param above:

```
&d=asdf%0A%0Aasdf
```

What  `.replace()` regex pattern do I need to do to handle the line break encoding, `%0A`?

EDIT:
I'm already successfully converting the URL params to a javascript object. The problem is that the `replace([pattern match])` functions inside are choking on the mutliline text character: `%0A`.

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.parse` in the first place? That's not a JSON-formatted string.

Comment: I'm converting the URL params to a json object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert URL parameters to a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object)

Comment: No. It works fine already to parse into a JSON object. The problem is specifically how to successfully decode the line break code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the query string using `URLSearchParams`, and then use `URLSearchParams`'s `entries` method to turn it into a plain Javascript object, and then stringify it to turn it into a JSON-formatted string:

```js
const queryString = '?cn=asdf%20asdf&pn=asdf%20asdf&pe=asdf%40example.com&d=asdf%0A%0Aasdf&ye=test%40example.com&c=1234&tc=true';
const params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
console.log(params.get('d'));
const queryObj = {};
for (const [key, val] of params.entries()) {
  queryObj[key] = val;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(queryObj));
```

Comment: Good solution. I’ll give it a try.