# finding fields and making objects out of it with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to achieve to make a object from a string.

```
location=new%20york&start_date=2020-06-01T00%3A00&end_date=2020-06-24T23%3A59&type=ADD&actor_uuid=f4927094-a682-4817-a6e4-03f4f6cb5h62&group_uuid=a8fc84a5-ab4d-7455-ydu5-ccbbcd2ddc79&group_uuid=af372af8-6e38-40fb-9e2e-adc5425ec50c&access_name=admin
```

So the above is the string I am having it from front and processing it in backend want to store it in mongodb using mongoose

My request body:

```
{
    "City": "New York",   
    "type": "BILLED",
    "details":"location=new%20york&start_date=2020-06-01T00%3A00&end_date=2020-06-24T23%3A59&type=ADD&actor_uuid=f4927094-a682-4817-a6e4-03f4f6cb5h62&group_uuid=a8fc84a5-ab4d-7455-ydu5-ccbbcd2ddc79&group_uuid=af372af8-6e38-40fb-9e2e-adc5425ec50c&access_name=admin"
}
```

Expected output respose -

```
 {
  City: "New York",
  type: "BILLED",
  details: {
    And: [
      {
        _id: "objectid",
        field: "location",
        value: "new york",
        operator: "equal"
      },
      {
        _id: "objectid",
        field: "start_date",
        value: "2020-06-01T00 3A00",
        operator: "equal"
      },
      {
        _id: "objectid",
        field: "end_date",
        value: "2020-06-24T23 3A59",
        operator: "equal"
      },
      {
        _id: "objectid",
        field: "type",
        value: "ADD",
        operator: "equal"
      },
      {
        _id: "objectid",
        field: "actor_uuid",
        value: "f4927094-a682-4817-a6e4-03f4f6cb5h62",
        operator: "equal"
      },
      {
        _id: "objectid",
        field: "group_uuid",
        value: "a8fc84a5-ab4d-7455-ydu5-ccbbcd2ddc79",
        operator: "equal"
      },
      {
        _id: "objectid",
        field: "group_uuid",
        value: "af372af8-6e38-40fb-9e2e-adc5425ec50c",
        operator: "equal"
      },
      {
        _id: "objectid",
        field: "access_name",
        value: "admin",
        operator: "equal"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Where I want to store it under conditions something like above, Now How can I achieve this?
Also how do I make sure and prevent sql injections?

Comment: With `URLSearchParams`, you have the right primitive to transform data as you like. Example: `const params = new URLSearchParams(object.details); [...params].forEach(([key, value]) => {console.log(key, '=', value)})`.

Comment: Why dont you use `querystring` module ? `const qs = require('querystring'); let object = qs.parse(details)`

Comment: @Mahan `Why dont you use querystring module ?`: Because there is no need for that since URLSearchParams is a native JavaScript object.

Comment: Not getting the expected output, Can you help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert URL parameters to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/how-to-convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object)

Comment: How can I achieve the above scenario?