# How to convert string to json - java script

Tags: javascript, json

I have this string

```
_token=mRdKQDuJYgNSPW8ixwZ2pgnTDpek5GM3O5OptdbX&edit_saved_report=&start_date=2022-02-14&end_date=2022-02-14&timezone=US%2FEastern&dsp_id%5B%5D=&ssp_id%5B%5D=&pub_id%5B%5D=&deal_id%5B%5D=&agency_id%5B%5D=&brand_id%5B%5D=&deal_personnel%5B%5D=&deal_type%5B%5D=&device_type=&media_type=
```

how I can convert it to json using java script?
I need it to be key -> value pairs     and not as html

this is the soloution:            `let test2 =  JSON.parse('{"' + sagidata.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}', function(key, value) { return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) })`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert URL parameters to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/how-to-convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object)

Comment: There no language named `java script` there is `java` or `javascript` at which one do you refer your question ?

Comment: `Object.fromEntries([...new URLSearchParams('_token=mRdKQDuJYgNSPW8ixwZ2pgnTDpek5GM3O5OptdbX&edit_saved_report=&start_date=2022-02-14&end_date=2022-02-14&timezone=US%2FEastern&dsp_id%5B%5D=&ssp_id%5B%5D=&pub_id%5B%5D=&deal_id%5B%5D=&agency_id%5B%5D=&brand_id%5B%5D=&deal_personnel%5B%5D=&deal_type%5B%5D=&device_type=&media_type=').entries()])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

**Working Demo :**

```js
let str = "_token=mRdKQDuJYgNSPW8ixwZ2pgnTDpek5GM3O5OptdbX&edit_saved_report=&start_date=2022-02-14&end_date=2022-02-14&timezone=US%2FEastern&dsp_id%5B%5D=&ssp_id%5B%5D=&pub_id%5B%5D=&deal_id%5B%5D=&agency_id%5B%5D=&brand_id%5B%5D=&deal_personnel%5B%5D=&deal_type%5B%5D=&device_type=&media_type=";

let obj = {};

str.split('&').forEach((elem) => {
    obj[elem.split('=')[0]] = elem.split('=')[1] 
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Why `forEach` instead of `reduce`?

Comment: As we are not doing any manipulations in the elements. We are just going to assign a properties in an object. Hence, I used `forEach` over `map`.

Comment: You could write `const obj = str.split('&').reduce((acc, elem) => ..., {})`

Comment: Only problem here is that `timezone: "US/Eastern"` is not getting decoded correctly.  or `dsp_id[]` etc.

Comment: `reduce` shouldn't be used as a panacea for all iteration issues. `forEach` is a solid solution.

Comment: this solved it:                                      let test2 =  JSON.parse('{"' + sagidata.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}', function(key, value) { return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) })