# How to get string between 2 words specifically?

Tags: javascript

I need to access the value in a string between 2 words.
In my string I have 2 words : `entityID=`and `=menu`. Between those 2 words I have an number which can be in single character like 1-9 or two or more characters.
I want to tell to javascript, find me the characters between 'entityId=' and '=menu'.

[EDIT]

I tried with this function but no success :

```js
function getId(str, start, end) {
    const result = str.match(new RegExp(start + "(.*)" + end));

    return result[1];
}

getId(myString, 'entityId= ', '&menu')
```

but I got an errror

Any idea ?

Comment: What is holding you back? Any attempt?

Comment: "but I got an errror" - what was the error message?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you have and what you expect

Comment: if you use split, it might help. also, include the actual string you are passing in. that would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert URL parameters to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/how-to-convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What the question was about

If you are sure that the `entityId=` and the `&menu=` key are provided, you can use the method split to retrieve your string as the following example

```js
const string = "http://myAmazingUrl?entityId=100101010&menu=1"

const word = string.split("entityId=")[1].split("&menu")[0]

console.log(word)
```

---

## A little more

Here, it seems that you are trying to retrieve the key of a request.

I would suggest you to use the [Url object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and retrieve your parameters using `searchParams`

```js
const url = new URL("http://myAmazingUrl?entityId=100101010&menu=1");
const entityId = url.searchParams.get("entityId");
console.log(entityId);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should help.

```
function getStringInBetween(str, start, end) {
    const res = str.match(new RegExp(start + "(.*)" + end));
    return res[1];
}

const string = 'Hello my Stack Overflow friends';

console.log(getStringInBetween(string, 'Hello ', ' Stack'));
```

-- Output --

my