# How to URL-encode ParsedUrlQuery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm migrating from vanilla React to NextJS. Before the change, I got my URL query params (the part after the `?` in the URL) through `react-router`'s `useSearchParams` hook, which returns [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

NextJS's router, however, returns the query params in the form of [ParsedUrlQuery](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules__types_node_querystring_d_._querystring_.parsedurlquery.html).
I want to forward these `ParsedUrlQuery` parameters to my (Express) backend server, again in the form of URL query params (the same form they are shown in the website's URL) but I can't figure out how to URL-encode them.

Here is my old code. **I need to replace `URLSearchParams` for `ParsedUrlQuery`. Or alternatively, transform the `ParsedUrlQuery` into `URLSearchParams`  How can I do that?**

```
export async function searchResources(searchParams: URLSearchParams): Promise<SearchResourcesResponse> {
    const response = await fetchWithTimeout(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TUTHUB_SERVER_URL + '/resources?' + searchParams
    )
    const resources = await response.json();
    return resources;
};
```

Comment: How a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/how-to-convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT

Simplest method: use the the `encode/stringify` method included in the `querystring` lib

```js
import { encode } from 'querystring'

// From useRouter:
// const { query } = useRouter()

// From GetServerSidePropContext
// const { query } = ctx

const urlQueryString = encode(query)
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(urlQueryString )
```

### OLD ANSWER

Or you can use these helper methods to transform the query params from one type to another in a very simple way.

```js
export function parsedUrlQueryToURLSearchParams(
  query: ParsedUrlQuery
): URLSearchParams {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams()
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(query)) {
    if (!value) continue
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach((element) => {
        searchParams.append(key, element)
      })
    } else {
      searchParams.append(key, value)
    }
  }
  return searchParams
}

export function urlSearchParamsToParsedUrlQuery(
  searchParams: URLSearchParams
): ParsedUrlQuery {
  const query: ParsedUrlQuery = {}
  for (var [key, value] of searchParams.entries()) {
    query[key] = value
  }
  return query
}
```

If you want, you can also create another helper method to transform the query object from next/router to an encoded string

```js
export function parsedUrlQueryToURLString(query: ParsedUrlQuery): string {
  const params = []
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(query)) {
    if (!value) continue
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach((element) => {
        params.push(`${key}=${encodeURIComponent(element)}`)
      })
    } else {
      params.push(`${key}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
    }
  }
  return params.join('&')
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That stringify method was hard to find.