# Deserialize jQuery form to vue 3

Tags: jquery, vue.js

How can I deserialize form if before I did so deserialize with jQuery? But now I use vue 3 and I need to deserialize with `JSON.parse`.

I store all data in Postgres and I need to deserialize with old name input.

```
var form_generate_page = "left_margin=1&right_margin=1&up_margin=1&bot_margin=1.7&secondColumnMarginTop=0&firstColumnMarginTop=0&marginMiddle=5&firstColumnMarginRight=5&DistanceBetweenLine=10.03176&mirror_margin=on&adding_space=on&different_marginTop=0&different_marginTopEven=5.5&different_marginTopOdd=5.7&different_marginLeft=0&different_marginLeftEven=0&different_marginLeftOdd=0";
                $("#form-generate-page").deserialize(form_generate_page);
```

I use different name input and name object

```
<input name="left_margin" v-model="object.left"/>
```

Script:

```
data () {
return{
    localMainPdf:{
        leftMargin:2,
        rightMargin:2,
        topMargin:2,
        bottomMargin:2,
    }
}
} 

clickTestSetProps() {
// data from DB
      var form_generate_page = "left_margin=1&right_margin=1&up_margin=1&bot_margin=1.7&secondColumnMarginTop=0&firstColumnMarginTop=0&marginMiddle=5&firstColumnMarginRight=5&DistanceBetweenLine=10.03176&mirror_margin=on&adding_space=on&different_marginTop=0&different_marginTopEven=5.5&different_marginTopOdd=5.7&different_marginLeft=0&different_marginLeftEven=0&different_marginLeftOdd=0";
    $("#form-generate-page").deserialize(form_generate_page);
    
    
                },
```

Template:

```
<form id ="form-generate-page">
<input  name = "left_margin" type="number" v-model="localMainPdf.leftMargin" step="any"  >
 <input  name = "right_margin" type="number" v-model="localMainPdf.rightMargin" step="any" >
 <input  name = "up_margin" type="number" v-model="localMainPdf.topMargin" step="any" >
 <input  name = "bot_margin" type="number" v-model="localMainPdf.bottomMargin" step="any" >
</form>
```

If I do this:

```
$("#form-generate-page").deserialize(form_generate_page);
```

data in mainPdf doesn't change

Comment: Your string is in the same form as URL parameters, so I did a search.  Does this answer your question? [How to convert URL parameters to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/how-to-convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object). It should work the same for your use case

Comment: I use different name input and name object

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly you're trying to do.  Can you explain the end goal, what your component's data looks like and/or what data you're receiving and what the final result should be?

Comment: I think you mean to use `localMainPdf.leftMargin` as the v-model.  `<input name="left_margin" v-model="localMainPdf.leftMargin"/>`. this will two-way bind the input value to that data property.

Comment: @yoduh i get data from DB In this format "left_margin=1&right_margin=1&" and I need to send this data to model