# decodeURI decodes space as + symbol

Tags: javascript, decode

I have created a Google Custom Search. The logic is when a user search, the page will display result and the title of the page will be changed to the search term using javascript. I use decodeURI to decode the unicode characters. But the space is decode as +. For example if  I search money making it will be decoded as money+making and it is displayed as title. Someone please help to solve this. I want to display space instead of the symbol +.

The code is

```
 if (query != null){document.title = decodeURI(query)+" | Tamil Search";}</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't decodeURI("a+b") == "a b"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535288/why-doesnt-decodeuriab-a-b)

Comment: (specifically this answer seems to solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4535319/1180785)

Answer (score 32):

The [Google Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) provides  its own urlDecode function for just this reason. You can either use the library or below is the [open source solution](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3178.1/third_party/google_input_tools/third_party/closure_library/closure/goog/string/string.js?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F#486) for how they solve it.

```
/**
 * URL-decodes the string. We need to specially handle '+'s because
 * the javascript library doesn't convert them to spaces.
 * @param {string} str The string to url decode.
 * @return {string} The decoded {@code str}.
 */
goog.string.urlDecode = function(str) {
  return decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
```

Comment: javascript is full of surprises. One would bet decodeURIComponent (from its name) should also handle this case.

Comment: Since you are decoding it just after I would prefer replacing the old + symbol for its current one %20, so ```decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\+/g, '%20'))```

Comment: Don't you mean `decodeURIComponent(filename).replace(/\+/g, ' ');`?

Comment: @PeterMoore if the `filename` contains `%2B`, `a %2B b` will turn into `a   b`

Answer (score 8):

You can use replace function for this:

```
decodeURI(query).replace( /\+/g, ' ' )
```

Comment: This does not always work. If a user searches for "A+B C" an HTML form will encode it as "A%2B+C". The code above will decode this as "A%2B C". Instead you should first replace all +s with spaces then use decodeURIComponent (since we are not decoding a full URI but rather one parameter).