# reverse function to encodeURI()

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a component that integrate between two 3rd-party libraries.

Gets a URL from the first library, and pass it to the second library.

The URL i get is in the format of:

https://xxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx_xx_xx/xxxx_xx_xx/xxxxxxxx/g_19743dff-0931-40c4-ac5a-10fd1150bda4/x/xxxxxxxx_xxxx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xxxx_xxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxxx.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFACFRGCGV7RPFKQ&Expires=1445259633&Signature=RD35q%2BlEc4Lkn5ppfM2QTKsDCTo%3D

meaning it include signs like "=" and "+" in encoded format.

When I pass it to the second library as-is, the library failed to download the file.
From the source of that library I see that it tries to perform 'encode(url)' before downloading the file, which cause it to be encoded again with no need.

I tried decoding the URL before transferring it to the second library (with *decodeURI* or *decodeURIComponent*), so it will then encode it and successfully download the file, but encode() doesn't encode all chars, it has some reserved-char (like '+' and '='), so the result url wasn't end up the same as the original.

To sum-up my question:

Assuming i don't have any control over the code of the 2 libraries, given 'encodedUrl', how can I implement 'myFunc(str)' such that:

```
encodeURI(myFunc(encodedUrl)) === encodedUrl
```

for every url possible.

Comment: Could you post the original string as well.

Comment: @LGSon I did, it's the url in the question. just replaced some alphabet chars to 'x' to hide private data

Comment: The major issue with this is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010119/decodeuri-decodes-space-as-symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the first library gives you encoded urls, you can't. For example, `myFunc` could only turn "%2B" into "+", because "+" is the only thing `encodeURI` would turn into "%2B". That makes `myFunc === decodeURIComponent`, and you know what that means.