# Replace a String in Javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

my input is 
var email = "xyz+wex+rr%40gmail.com";

i need output as

xyz wex rr @ gmail.com

i have tried with this below regex , i can only remove + from my string how to replace %40 with @

email .replace(/+/g, " ");

Comment: You will have to escape characters that have special meaning in regex like `+`. Try `/\+/g`

Comment: Simply run another replace with "\%40" as search string to be replaced.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20247435/2329980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is required solution,

`email.replace(/\+/g, " ").replace(/\%40/g, "@")`

```js
var email = "xyz+wex+rr%40gmail.com";
console.log(email.replace(/\+/g, " ").replace(/\%40/g, "@"))
```

Result: `xyz wex rr@gmail.com`

**Please run the above snippet**

Answer (score 3):

```js
var email = "xyz+wex+rr%40gmail.com";
email = decodeURIComponent(email).replace(/\+/g, " ");
console.log(email);
```

decodeURIComponent decodes things like %40. It only does not replace the `+` signs with spaces, so this is done with a RegEx, escaping the plus sign, which has a special meaning in RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unescape function to first unescape the string and than replace `+`with

Try this one

```js
var email = unescape("xyz+wex+rr%40gmail.com").replace(/[+]/g, " ");
console.log(email)
```

As @Florian Albrecht said that `unescape` is deprecated so deprecated Florian's answer is better

Comment: unescape is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Comment: thanks for sharing