# Firebase dynamic link shortner api converts all (spaces) %20 to (plus) + in embeded link

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using firebase dynamic link shortener api to create dynamic links, in request I'm passing long link which contains query params having message that I want to render in my application. But  when I open short link (which I got in response), all spaces passed in long link gets converted to +, I tried to create similar link from firebase dashboard but getting the same issue.

I used the api given in document below
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is to be expected and should be natively supported by browsers as long as any `+` symbols follow the query delimiter, `?`.

---

Per the [RFC3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) specification, its obsoleted forms [RF2396](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2396), [RF1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738) and the many linked changes over the years, the space character (`0x20`) MUST be encoded in a URI.

For compatibility with all schemes, it MUST be percent-encoded as `%20`.

However, the query component of a URI with a scheme of `http:` or `https:` has a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This content type specifies that spaces are to be encoded as `+`, the reserved characters are to be escaped according to the URI spec, and that non-alphanumeric characters are to be percent-encoded as `%HH`.

So essentially, this mean that `+` is converted back to a space after the `?` in a URI with a scheme of `http` or `https`.

Examples:

```js
// URI of a StackOverflow search for "RFC 3986"
"https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RFC+3986"   // ✔ (default used by StackOverflow)
"https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RFC%203986" // ✔
"https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RFC 3986"   // ✖ (prohibited character)

// URI of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
"file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Notepad++\notepad++.exe" // ✔
"file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Notepad%2B%2B\notepad%2B%2B.exe" // ✔ (verbose, but valid)
"file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++\notepad++.exe" // ✖ (spaces must be encoded)
"file:///C:/Program+Files+(x86)/Notepad++\notepad++.exe" // ✖ (not found, `+` not decoded to space)
```

From [RFC3986 Section 2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.2):

> The purpose of reserved characters is to provide a set of delimiting characters that are distinguishable from other data within a URI. URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its corresponding percent-encoded octet are not equivalent. Percent-encoding a reserved character, or decoding a percent-encoded octet that corresponds to a reserved character, will change how the URI is interpreted by most applications. Thus, characters in the reserved set are protected from normalization and are therefore safe to be used by scheme-specific and producer-specific algorithms for delimiting data subcomponents within a URI.

Because of that above statement, it's important to note that many `decodeURI`/`decodeURIComponent` functions will not decode a `+` to a space. It is up to your code to add support for that such as how the [Google Closure Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20247435/3068190) swaps them out for spaces before decoding:

```
/**
 * URL-decodes the string. We need to specially handle '+'s because
 * the javascript library doesn't convert them to spaces.
 * @param {string} str The string to url decode.
 * @return {string} The decoded {@code str}.
 */
goog.string.urlDecode = function(str) {
  return decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
```