# In Ruby/Rails, how can I encode/escape special characters in URLs?

Tags: ruby, urlencode, open-uri

How do I encode or 'escape' the URL before I use OpenURI to `open(url)`?

We're using OpenURI to open a remote url and return the xml:

```
getresult = open(url).read
```

The problem is the URL contains some user-input text that contains spaces and other characters, including "+", "&", "?", etc. potentially, so we need to safely escape the URL. I saw lots of examples when using Net::HTTP, but have not found any for OpenURI.

We also need to be able to un-escape a similar string we receive in a session variable, so we need the reciprocal function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has the built-in [URI](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/uri/1.9.2/frames) library, and the [Addressable](http://rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/2.2.4/frames) gem, in particular [Addressable::URI](http://rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/2.2.4/Addressable/URI)

I prefer Addressable::URI. It's very full featured and handles the encoding for you when you use the `query_values=` method.

I've seen some discussions about URI going through some growing pains so I tend to leave it alone for handling encoding/escaping until these things get sorted out:

- http://osdir.com/ml/ruby-core/2010-06/msg00324.html
- http://osdir.com/ml/lang-ruby-core/2009-06/msg00350.html
- http://osdir.com/ml/ruby-core/2011-06/msg00748.html

Comment: The URI library is deprecated, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824126/whats-the-difference-between-uri-escape-and-cgi-escape

Answer (score 35):

Don't use `URI.escape` as it has been deprecated in 1.9.

Rails' Active Support adds [`Hash#to_query`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-to_query):

```
 {foo: 'asd asdf', bar: '"<#$dfs'}.to_query
 # => "bar=%22%3C%23%24dfs&foo=asd+asdf"
```

Also, as you can see it tries to order query parameters always the same way, which is good for HTTP caching.

Comment: in rails 4.2 i notice this runs the following code:
  "#{CGI.escape(key.to_param)}=#{CGI.escape(to_param.to_s)}"

Comment: @Ed_, thank you - I've pasted invalid link to Object#to_query, where it should be Hash#to_query.

Answer (score 15):

Ruby Standard Library to the rescue:

```
require 'uri'
user_text = URI.escape(user_text)
url = "http://example.com/#{user_text}"
result = open(url).read
```

See more at the [docs for the URI::Escape module](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/uri/1.9.2/URI/Escape:escape). It also has a method to do the inverse (`unescape`)

Comment: also very helpful thank you. not sure whether I'll use uri or addressable. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, just saw that URI.encode takes full URL. No wonder it's giving problems. So... Don't use it ;)

Comment: WTF?  URI.encode has an absolutely impossible spec; there's no way to identify the unescaped portions of a string - this is just a security leak waiting to happen.

Answer (score 8):

The main thing you have to consider is that you have to escape the keys and values separately **before** you compose the full URL.

All the methods which get the full URL and try to escape it afterwards are broken, because they cannot tell whether any `&` or `=` character was supposed to be a separator, or maybe a part of the value (or part of the key).

The CGI library seems to do a good job, except for the space character, which was traditionally encoded as `+`, and nowadays should be encoded as `%20`. But this is an easy fix.

Please, consider the following:

```
require 'cgi'

def encode_component(s)
  # The space-encoding is a problem:
  CGI.escape(s).gsub('+','%20')
end

def url_with_params(path, args = {})
  return path if args.empty?
  path + "?" + args.map do |k,v|
    "#{encode_component(k.to_s)}=#{encode_component(v.to_s)}" 
  end.join("&")
end

def params_from_url(url)
  path,query = url.split('?',2)
  return [path,{}] unless query
  q = query.split('&').inject({}) do |memo,p|
    k,v = p.split('=',2)
    memo[CGI.unescape(k)] = CGI.unescape(v)
    memo
  end
  return [path, q]
end

u = url_with_params( "http://example.com",
                            "x[1]"  => "& ?=/",
                            "2+2=4" => "true" )

# "http://example.com?x%5B1%5D=%26%20%3F%3D%2F&2%2B2%3D4=true"

params_from_url(u)
# ["http://example.com", {"x[1]"=>"& ?=/", "2+2=4"=>"true"}]
```

Comment: don't use CGI.escape, it goes against the spec and converts spaces to + instead of %20

Comment: I do not understand. The `+` is perfectly good when we talk about escaping space in a URI, I believe. Why do you think it is not supposed to be used?

Comment: Arsen7, the + is deprecated.  It's what was used in the old CGI days before URL encoding was standardized.  The only reason + still works is because of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Well, you are perfectly right, but the problem is that there was no other reliable way to properly escape an URI component at the time. The `CGI::escape` does everything properly, except the `+`, and you probably can just do a `gsub` on the result. But if you are using **ruby 1.9+**, then it seems like the function `URI.encode_www_form_component` could be used instead.