# How do I URL-escape a string in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, escaping

If I'm in an RHTML view in Rails, it is easy to URL-escape something:

```
<a href="/redirect?href=<%=u target %>">Foo</a>
```

How do I do this in a string? I'd like to do something like this:

```
<% redirect_href = "/redirect?#{url_escape target}&amp;foo=bar&amp;baz=some_other_stuff" -%>
<a href="<%= redirect_href =>">Foo</a>
```

This must be trivial, right?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[CGI.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape) will do it:

```
<% redirect_href = "/redirect?#{CGI.escape target}&amp;foo=bar&amp;baz=some_other_stuff" -%>
<a href="<%= redirect_href =>">Foo</a>
```

Comment: `CGI.escape` is not the best thing, as it encodes space as '+' which is deprecated and not always parses correctly on the other side.

For example, if you have Rails route "/my-path/:query" where query includes '+', it will stay as '+' after route parsing. To make it work better, use `ERB::Util.u(string)`, which escapes space as "%20".

Comment: To give an example of the issue with CGI.escape, a link like `link_to("hi", "mailto:foo@bar.com?body=#{CGI.escape("one two")}")` would give you the mail body "one+two" in Apple's desktop Mail.app.

Answer (score 74):

Rails (`activesupport`) defines `Hash#to_param` (aliased to `Hash#to_query`):

```
 {foo: 'asd asdf', bar: '"<#$dfs'}.to_param
 # => "bar=%22%3C%23%24dfs&foo=asd+asdf"
```

It's worth noting that it sorts query keys (for HTTP caching).

`Hash#to_param` also accepts optional namespace parameter:

```
{name: 'David', nationality: 'Danish'}.to_param('user')
# => "user[name]=David&user[nationality]=Danish"
```

**http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-to_param**

Comment: Seems like it's turning spaces into `+` not `%20`

`>> {y: "blah blah"}.to_query` outputs `"y=blah+blah"`

Answer (score 44):

[ERB::Util.url_encode](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB/Util.html#method-c-url_encode)

can be used from anywhere, part of ruby std lib.

Comment: You need this one if you want spaces to be represented as `%20`

Answer (score 11):

Use either `CGI::escape` or `ERB::Util.url_encode` but not `URI.encode`.

`URI.escape` has been deprecated circa Ruby 1.9.2: [What's the difference between URI.escape and CGI.escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824126/whats-the-difference-between-uri-escape-and-cgi-escape)