# Ruby on Rails: decoding params from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I begin to create a rails API for react. I pass a GET request with params inside url like this:

```
api/dashboard/price?"foo"="bar"
```

But my rails app by default cannot decode it properly and on backend side. My params object looks this way:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"\"foo\""=>"\"bar\"", "controller"=>"api/dashboards", "action"=>"price"} permitted: false>
```

Furthermore I cannot access any of those keys e.g:

```
params[:foo]
```

returns nil

How can I get rid of those slashes and decode url params proper way?

Comment: "I pass a GET request with params inside url like this" - there's your problem. Don't pass params like this (with quotes).

Comment: Have you tried to make a request without double quotes? `api/dashboard/price?foo=bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass url params with quotes `"foo"` then you should also access them with quotes like this: `params['"foo"']`.

But if you want to make `params[:foo]` work then just pass them without any quotes.
`api/dashboard/price?foo=bar`.

Comment: Agree with Dmitry, but don't do the first option. Just pass `api/dashboard/price?foo=bar`. It's much cleaner. If you need bar to be multiple words just URL escape it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057972/how-do-i-url-escape-a-string-in-rails