# How to URL encode a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, uri, urlencode

How do I `URI::encode` a string like:

```
\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a
```

to get it in a format like:

```
%124Vx%9A%BC%DE%F1%23Eg%89%AB%CD%EF%124Vx%9A
```

as per RFC 1738?

Here's what I tried:

```
irb(main):123:0> URI::encode "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a"
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:219:in `gsub'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:219:in `escape'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:505:in `escape'
    from (irb):123
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Also:

```
irb(main):126:0> CGI::escape "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a"
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/util.rb:7:in `gsub'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/util.rb:7:in `escape'
    from (irb):126
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I looked all about the internet and haven't found a way to do this, although I am almost positive that the other day I did this without any trouble at all.

Comment: Maybe useful if using Ruby 1.9: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/

Answer (score 204, accepted):

```
str = "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')
puts CGI.escape str


=> "%124Vx%9A%BC%DE%F1%23Eg%89%AB%CD%EF%124Vx%9A"
```

Comment: `force_encoding('binary')` might be a more self-documenting choice.

Comment: They deprecated that method, use * `CGI.escape` * instead. -> [http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/207489#903709](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/207489#903709). You should also be able to use  `URI.www_form_encode`
* `URI.www_form_encode_component` *, but I have never used those

Comment: No need to `require 'open-uri'` here. Did you mean `require 'uri'`?

Comment: @J-Rou, CGI.escape can escape whole URL, it does not selectively escapes query parameters, for instance, if you pass `'a=&!@&b=&$^'` to CGI.escape it will escape whole thing with query separators `&` so this could be used only to query values. I suggest using `addressable` gem , it is more intellectual working with urls.

Comment: I needed to access files on remote server. Encoding with CGI didn't work, but URI.encode did the work just fine.

Answer (score 117):

Nowadays, you should use `ERB::Util.url_encode` or `CGI.escape`. The primary difference between them is their handling of spaces:

```
>> ERB::Util.url_encode("foo/bar? baz&")
=> "foo%2Fbar%3F%20baz%26"

>> CGI.escape("foo/bar? baz&")
=> "foo%2Fbar%3F+baz%26"
```

`CGI.escape` follows the [CGI/HTML forms spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) and gives you an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string, which requires spaces be escaped to `+`, whereas `ERB::Util.url_encode` follows [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), which requires them to be encoded as `%20`.

See "[What's the difference between URI.escape and CGI.escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824126/whats-the-difference-between-uri-escape-and-cgi-escape/13059657#13059657)" for more discussion.

Comment: Neither of those commands are available in Ruby 2.7.3 and up. I think `nowadays` has passed.

Comment: @karatedog They're still around! You might need to `require 'erb'` or `require 'cgi'`.

Answer (score 73):

```
str = "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a"
require 'cgi'
CGI.escape(str)
# => "%124Vx%9A%BC%DE%F1%23Eg%89%AB%CD%EF%124Vx%9A"
```

Taken from @J-Rou's comment

Answer (score 14):

I was originally trying to escape special characters in a file name only, not on the path, from a full URL string.

`ERB::Util.url_encode` didn't work for my use:

```
helper.send(:url_encode, "http://example.com/?a=\11\15")
# => "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fa%3D%09%0D"
```

Based on two answers in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274838/why-is-uri-escape-marked-as-obsolete-and-where-is-this-regexpunsafe-constant", it looks like `URI::RFC2396_Parser#escape` is better than using `URI::Escape#escape`. However, they both are behaving the same to me:

```
URI.escape("http://example.com/?a=\11\15")
# => "http://example.com/?a=%09%0D"
URI::Parser.new.escape("http://example.com/?a=\11\15")
# => "http://example.com/?a=%09%0D"
```

UPDATE: I think it's from Ruby 3.0, `URI.escape` does not work any more. I have not found replacement except `URI::Parser.new.escape` yet.

Comment: The only actual answer that I could find. Thank you.

Comment: This whole issue is a mess!  Thanks for shedding some real light on it.  I wasted at least a day chasing my tail before finding this!

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Addressable::URI` gem for that:

```
require 'addressable/uri'   
string = '\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a'
Addressable::URI.encode_component(string, Addressable::URI::CharacterClasses::QUERY)
# "%5Cx12%5Cx34%5Cx56%5Cx78%5Cx9a%5Cxbc%5Cxde%5Cxf1%5Cx23%5Cx45%5Cx67%5Cx89%5Cxab%5Cxcd%5Cxef%5Cx12%5Cx34%5Cx56%5Cx78%5Cx9a"
```

It uses more modern format, than `CGI.escape`, for example, it properly encodes space as `%20` and not as `+` sign, you can read more in "[The application/x-www-form-urlencoded type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type)" on Wikipedia.

```
2.1.2 :008 > CGI.escape('Hello, this is me')
 => "Hello%2C+this+is+me" 
2.1.2 :009 > Addressable::URI.encode_component('Hello, this is me', Addressable::URI::CharacterClasses::QUERY)
 => "Hello,%20this%20is%20me"
```

Comment: Also can do like this: 
`CGI.escape('Hello, this is me').gsub("+", "%20")`
 `=> Hello%2C%20this%20is%20me"` if don't want to use any gems

Answer (score 8):

Code:

```
str = "http://localhost/with spaces and spaces"
encoded = URI::encode(str)
puts encoded
```

Result:

```
http://localhost/with%20spaces%20and%20spaces
```

Comment: If the receiving server is old, it might not respond well to CGI.escape. This is still a valid alternative.

Answer (score 6):

I created a gem to make URI encoding stuff cleaner to use in your code. It takes care of binary encoding for you.

Run `gem install uri-handler`, then use:

```
require 'uri-handler'

str = "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a".to_uri
# => "%124Vx%9A%BC%DE%F1%23Eg%89%AB%CD%EF%124Vx%9A"
```

It adds the URI conversion functionality into the String class. You can also pass it an argument with the optional encoding string you would like to use. By default it sets to encoding 'binary' if the straight UTF-8 encoding fails.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "encode" a full URL without having to think about manually splitting it into its different parts, I found the following worked in the same way that I used to use `URI.encode`:

```rb
URI.parse(my_url).to_s
```