# How to convert a ruby string to HTTP address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have this string URL for an HTTP request

```
http://locahost:3000/stuff?owner=foo bar+type=video game
```

I need to pass this as part of an HTTP get request to another ruby service. How do I encode this URL, i.e. take off the spaces and special characters and come up with the right request URL? Is there a gem to handle that. 
I know this could probably be done with some kind of regex, but I was hoping to find a standard gem that could do this.

Comment: This is an probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714196/ruby-url-encoding-string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'uri'
uri_string = URI::encode("http://localhost:3000/stuff?owner=foo bar+type=video game")
```

Not sure how searching for "ruby url encode" or parsing etc. didn't find that for you.