# How to convert strings to URLs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails application I need to convert Strings like

```
Friedrichtraße 123, Berlin, Germany
```

into URLs like

```
Friedrichstra%C3%9Fe+123,+Berlin,+Germany
```

How can this be done in Ruby?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714196/ruby-url-encoding-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'uri'

URI::encode("Friedrichtraße 123, Berlin, Germany")
#=> "Friedrichtra%C3%9Fe%20123,%20Berlin,%20Germany"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'cgi'

CGI.escape('Friedrichtraße 123, Berlin, Germany')
# => "Friedrichtra%C3%9Fe+123%2C+Berlin%2C+Germany"
```

Answer (score 1):

To the two sub-Rails answers I will add: Invoke `rake routes`, read in the first column the helper prefix of the URL you want - let's call it `home` - then pack your variables as hash options into `home_path`:

```
home_path(:address => 'Friedrichtraße 123, Berlin, Germany')
```