# Simple cipher to encode URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I want to encode a url (http://www.someurl.com) so that I can add it as a parameter to a GET call:

domain.com/encoded_url

Once received on the other end, I need to be able to decode the url, however, security is not an issue. I rather stick to a simple cipher (must be able to handle special characters like ':' and '?') since the more advanced ciphers produce encoded strings that do not pass as valid URI strings and can't be passed as URL parameters.

**What kind of cipher implemented in Ruby would work best for this purpose?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Use Base64.urlsafe_encode64

Base64 is a good idea to use, Ruby provides URL safe implementation of it, because the default will produce characters like + and =. `urlsafe_encode64` will use '-' instead of '+' and '_' instead of '+' so they can be passed like URL parameters.

```
require "base64"

encoded_url = Base64.urlsafe_encode64('http://www.someurl.com', ) #=> "aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zb21ldXJsLmNvbQ=="
decoded_url = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(encoded_url) #=> "http://www.someurl.com"
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/Base64/urlsafe_encode64

Comment: This is the better answer because urlsafe_encode64 will respect the uri spec on reserved tokens as you mention.

Comment: what would be js equivalent of `Base64.urlsafe_decode64(encoded_url)` ?

Comment: Note that result can still contain '=' unless you turn padding off: `encoded_url = Base64.urlsafe_encode64('http://www.someurl.com', padding:false)`

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to encode it and security is not an issue, just use `Base64` and then URI escape it.
But there's no need to, just uri escape it.

`str = Base64.encode64(url)`

`encoded_str = URI.encode(str)`

btw, this is a semi-possible duplicate

[Ruby url encoding string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714196/ruby-url-encoding-string)