# Why is URI.escape() marked as obsolete and where is this REGEXP::UNSAFE constant?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out what the default set of unsafe characters is for URI.escape in ruby 2.2.3. The [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html) say:

> By default uses REGEXP::UNSAFE

But I can't find that constant anywhere in the URI module.

Additionally, [this code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blame/trunk/lib/uri/common.rb#L97) (snippet below) has the escape / unescape methods marked as 'obsolete' since 2009. Why are they obsolete?

```
lib/uri/common.rb:97

def escape(*arg)
  warn "#{caller(1)[0]}: warning: URI.escape is obsolete" if $VERBOSE
  DEFAULT_PARSER.escape(*arg)
end
```

Are the docs just wrong / out of date?

Comment: Don't say "this code" and provide a link. Instead, extract ONLY the code pertinent to your discussion and put it into your question. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Consider it this way: links rot, and when that one does will your question make as much sense for others looking for the same answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see you answered your question re: `UNSAFE`. As to this question:

> Additionally, [this code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blame/trunk/lib/uri/common.rb#L97) has the escape / unescape methods marked as 'obsolete' since 2009. Why are they obsolete?

There's some background in this Dec. 2010 issue: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4167 In that thread Yui Naruse writes:

> URI lib says it refers RFC2396, so current behavior is correct in its
>   spec.
>
> Yes, I know current behavior is not what you expect. So we plan to
>   change the lib to refer RFC3986.
>
> Moreover current URI.encode is simple gsub. But I think it should
>   split a URI to components, then escape each components, and finally
>   join them.
>
> So current URI.encode is considered harmful and deprecated. This will
>   be removed or change behavior drastically.
>
> > What is the replacement at this time?
>
> As I said above, current URI.encode is wrong on spec level. So we
>   won't provide the exact replacement. The replacement will vary by its
>   use case.
>
> We thought most use case is to generate escaped URI from joined URI
>   componets. For this, people should use URI.join or
>   URI.encode_www_form; you should escape each components before join
>   them.

Comment: As the quote says `URI.encode_www_form` is safe. It's also easy to use. [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) is a very worthy gem that I prefer if I have to do anything with lots of URIs.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out the docs are not quite accurate with regard to the default constant. If we look at

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blame/trunk/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb#L299

it's no longer a constant, but a member of a hash. So the default can really be examined like this:

```
> URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:UNSAFE]
=> /[^\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&=+$,\[\]]/
```

EDIT: Appears you can get it with simply:

```
> URI::UNSAFE
=> /[^\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&=+$,\[\]]/
```

Comment: The actual regex is here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/832c74f428db6c5bd6e575e1f6ea7fe0891c84d2/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb#L514

Answer (score 5):

There is an alternative, so if you are using the **addressable** gem, you can use [::escape](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sporkmonger/addressable/Addressable/URI#encode-class_method) method of its URI module as well as of the regular URI.

```rb
Addressable::URI.escape(value)
```