# Undefined method `escape' for URI:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-7, rubymotion

When I run this command this error shows up:

```
qppn@MacBook-Pro hello % motion support
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/command.rb:140:in guess_email_address': undefined method escape' for URI:Module (NoMethodError)

      URI.escape(`git config --get user.email`.strip)
         ^^^^^^^
    from /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/command/support.rb:36:in `run'
    from /Library/RubyMotion/vendor/CLAide/lib/claide/command.rb:277:in `run'
    from /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/command.rb:106:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bin/motion:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please add some context - what URI module are you using, and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the application tries to call `URI.escape` while running on Ruby 3.0+. `URI.escape` was deprecated in [Ruby 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274838/why-is-uri-escape-marked-as-obsolete-and-where-is-this-regexpunsafe-constant) and removed from Ruby 3.0.

To fix this issue, the application needs to be updated, or the application needs to be run with Ruby 2.7. The latter is not recommended, because Ruby 2.7 reached end-of-life March 2023 and is unmaintained.

Comment: RubyMotion apps are statically compiled using a custom Ruby implementation based on MRI 1.9.  The system Ruby is only used by the build system.