# How can i send Korean string in URL?(Ruby on Rails using HTTParty gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, httparty

My code is

```
resp = HTTParty.get("http://sandbox.api.simsimi.com/request.p?key=e7501386-fca8-4723-b278-36755e917526&lc=ko&ft=1.0&text=#{params[:content]}")
```

and params[:content] is `"안녕"` now.

if i run this code,

I get following error

```
URI must be ascii only "http://sandbox.api.simsimi.com/request.p?key=e7501386-fca8-4723-b278-36755e917526&lc=ko&ft=1.0&text=\u00ED\u0095\u0098\u00EC\u009D\u00B4" (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

How can i send Korean string in URL?

```
(.encode("utf-8) is not working..)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says "URI must be ascii only", you may encode Korean to URI format as below.

```
require 'uri'
str = "안녕".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT') # "\xEC\x95\x88\xEB\x85\x95"
URI::encode(str) # %EC%95%88%EB%85%95
```

Further info lies here: [Ruby url encoding string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714196/)