# Why doesn't URI.escape escape single quotes?

Tags: ruby, url, uri

Why doesn't `URI.escape` escape single quotes?

```
URI.escape("foo'bar\" baz")
=> "foo'bar%22%20baz"
```

Comment: Because a single quote is a legal URI character.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid

Comment: Well.. they are reserved though, meaning they are allowed but have special syntactical meaning. In this case I don't want them to have special meaning, it's data a user entered and it should not be interpreted as syntax but as data by the browser and by the web application and all the layers in between. So I guess the real question is, what does "escape" mean...

Comment: According to [the docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/URI/Escape/escape) it'll escape "unsafe" chars as defined by `REGEX::UNSAFE`. You can pass in your own.

Comment: FWIW I'm here because AWS Cloudfront expects single quotes in URIs to be escaped to `%27`, when you try to run an invalidation.  So, it's legal to some and not legal to others I guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the same reason it doesn't escape `?` or `/` or `:`, and so forth. `URI.escape()` only escapes characters that cannot be used in URLs *at all*, not characters that have a special meaning.

What you're looking for is [`CGI.escape()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape):

```
require "cgi"
CGI.escape("foo'bar\" baz")
=> "foo%27bar%22+baz"
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that's at all helpful.  CGI escape doesn't do the same things that URI escape did, and they aren't interchangeable.

Comment: @cbmanica. This is true, but most people who use this library are actually looking to URL-encode a string. See [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13059657/182590) for a great rundown on the alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but the answer hasn't been updated in a long time. I thought I'd update this for others who are having the same problem. The solution I found was [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832003/1376536): use `ERB::Util.url_encode` if you have the `erb` module available. This took care of single quotes & `*` for me as well.

`CGI::escape` doesn't escape spaces correctly (`%20`) versus plus signs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, `URI.escape(str [, unsafe])` uses a regexp that matches all symbols that must be replaced with codes. By default the method uses REGEXP::UNSAFE. When this argument is a String, it represents a character set.

In your case, to modify `URI.escape` to escape even the single quotes you can do something like this ...

```
reserved_characters = /[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\_\~]/
URI.escape(YOUR_STRING, reserved_characters)
```

Explanation: Some info on the spec ...

> All parameter names and values are escaped using the [rfc3986]
>   percent- encoding (%xx) mechanism. Characters not in the unreserved
>   character set ([rfc3986] section 2.3) must be encoded. characters in
>   the unreserved character set must not be encoded. hexadecimal
>   characters in encodings must be upper case. text names and values must
>   be encoded as utf-8 octets before percent-encoding them per [rfc3629].

Comment: URI.escape is deprecated. Even though it still exists, it's best to use one of the other solutions posted here.

Comment: @MarkThomas I agree. I put this here for archive purposes to elaborate how to modify the regex as it was mentioned in passing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but what I wanted was something slightly different, and I thought I might as well post it up: I wanted to keep the "/" in the url, but escape all the other non-standard characters.  I did it thus:

```
#public filename is a *nix filepath, 
#like `"/images/isn't/this a /horrible filepath/hello.png"`

public_filename.split("/").collect{|s| ERB::Util.url_encode(s)}.join("/")
=> "/images/isn%27t/this%20a%20/horrible%20filepath/hello.png"
```

I needed to escape the single quote as I was writing a cache invalidation for AWS Cloudfront, which didn't like the single quotes and expected them to be escaped.  The above should make a uri which is more safe than the standard URI.escape but which still looks like a URI (CGI Escape breaks the uri format by escaping "/").