# CGI::escape error after replacing URI.escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cgi, uri

[What's the difference between URI.escape and CGI.escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824126/whats-the-difference-between-uri-escape-and-cgi-escape) this post was talking about replacing URI.escape with `CGI::escape` as URI.escape has been obsolete. In our `rails 3.2` app, `URI.escape` was used for `redirect_to`. Here is two cases in our rails app:

```
URI.escape(SUBURI + '/user_menus')
URI.escape(SUBURI + '/authentify/signin')
```

Here are the match in `routes.rb`:

```
match '/signin',  :to => 'authentify::sessions#new'
match '/user_menus', :to => 'user_menus#index'
match '/view_handler', :to => 'authentify::application#view_handler'
```

After replacing with `CGI::escape`, there is error:

```
 ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part:
```

After removing the `CGI::escape`, the error disappears. Another example:

```
redirect_to CGI::escape(SUBURI + "/authentify/view_handler?index=0&msg=Insufficient Access Right! for action=#{action} and resource=#{resource}")
```

After replacing with CGI::escape, there is the error (as above).

What's wrong with the use of CGI::escape above? What's the exact equivalent of URI.escape? ? Also when will URI.escape be completely phased out?

Comment: irb(main):001:0> URI.escape('/nbhy/projectx_projects_path')
=> "/nbhy/projectx_projects_path"
irb(main):002:0> CGI::escape('/nbhy/projectx_projects_path')
=> "%2Fnbhy%2Fprojectx_projects_path"

Comment: URL helper is something new to us but I do see reason of why not if URL helper is a viable solution. Currently we are using URL.escape for almost every redirect_to in the app. We notice that it was deprecated and is looking for its equivalent. We are looking for something similar to URI.escape to handle the URL escaping.

Comment: ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html. There is URI.escape module in ruby 2.0.0. Why was it deprecated?

Comment: /authentify/view_handler is a method to record the previous page visited.

Comment: We are using helper if you meant _path generated by routes.