# Turning a json string into a URL encoded string (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

How I convert this json var

```
email = {"email":"name@gmail.com"}
```

into this encoded string?

```
%7B%22email%22%3A%22name%40gmail.com%22%7D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can use the `uri` library shown [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html)

```
[2] pry(main)> require 'uri'
=> true
[3] pry(main)> URI.encode('{"email":"name@gmail.com"}')
=> "%7B%22email%22:%22name@gmail.com%22%7D"
```

Comment: This won't work with JSON arrays. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55382212/165673)

Answer (score 1):

Use **CGI.escape**, NOT URI.encode/escape. URI.encode will  not escape the brackets of JSON arrays.

```
emails = '{"list_1":[{"Jim":"jim@gmail.com"},{"Joe":"joe@gmail.com"}]}'
> URI::encode(emails)
=> "%7B%22list_1%22:[%7B%22Jim%22:%22jim@gmail.com%22%7D,%7B%22Joe%22:%22joe@gmail.com%22%7D]%7D"
> CGI.escape(emails)
=> "%7B%22list_1%22%3A%5B%7B%22Jim%22%3A%22jim%40gmail.com%22%7D%2C%7B%22Joe%22%3A%22joe%40gmail.com%22%7D%5D%7D"
```

[ruby - What's the difference between URI.escape and CGI.escape - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824126/whats-the-difference-between-uri-escape-and-cgi-escape)