# How to transform white spaces into plus (+) characters for an http url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I am about to do a similar curl call like this:

```
curl https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/1600+pennsylvania+ave+nw.json
```

When I enter my own address, it looks like this: `1600 pennsylvania ave nw`. I tried to convert the white spaces to the `+` characters with using the `URI.encode` method:

```
address = URI.encode(full_address)
```

But the result is `1600%20pennsylvania%20ave%20nw`, which, after all, seems to be a correct output, however it doesn't solve my problem.

As a possible solution is to manually convert and replace every character, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Why does it matter? `pancakes+house` and `pancakes%20house` should be identical as far as mapbox.com is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
CGI.escape
```

instead.  This probably converts a string so you can send it as an html parameter, ex:

```
CGI.escape "http://something that needs to be encoded"
=> "http%3A%2F%2Fsomething+that+needs+to+be+encoded"
```

Also see [What's the difference between URI.escape and CGI.escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824126/whats-the-difference-between-uri-escape-and-cgi-escape)

Answer (score 1):

Break down the problem:

```
require 'uri'

path, filename = File.split('/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/1600 pennsylvania ave nw.json')
```

URI paths are file paths to a resource, so you can use `File.split` to get the path and filename.

```
uri = URI.parse('https://api.mapbox.com')
uri.path = [path, URI.encode_www_form_component(filename)].join('/')
```

Rebuild the URI's path from the path and the encoded filename, which gives you:

```
uri.to_s
# => "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/1600+pennsylvania+ave+nw.json"
```

It seems to me that using `%20` should be the right way to encode spaces in a path, but that would be determined by how they wrote their code.

You could use `gsub` if you're only dealing with converting spaces to `+`, but that'd miss necessary encoding if other characters were present that required it. URI follows the RFC which `gsub` wouldn't unless you wrote a lot more code.

I'd recommend looking at [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) also. It's a very full-featured gem for processing URIs.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), but I suggest to do this for the file name/your address only not for the whole url:

```
"1600 pennsylvania   ave     nw.json".squeeze(" ").gsub(" ", "+")
# => "1600+pennsylvania+ave+nw.json"
```