# DateTime to RFC3339 formatting issue as URL

Tags: ruby, datetime

I am trying to pass a DateTime in RFC3339 format to an API but it keeps getting rejected as being improperly formatted. Is there a different way to convert to the correct format?

```
require 'cgi'
require 'date'
require 'uri'

startTime=CGI.escape(DateTime.new(2016, 6, 6, 15, 47, 40).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
endTime=CGI.escape(DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
puts startTime #start=2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A40Z   me:2016-05-19T16%3A47%3A04-04%3A00
puts endTime
hist_data=getData(startTime,endTime)

def getData(startTime,endTime)
  base="https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument="
  curr="EUR_USD"
  granularity="H1"
  #https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument=EUR_USD&start=2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A40Z&end=2014-06-19T15%3A47%3A50Z
  myurl = "#{ base }#{ curr }&candleFormat=bidask&granularity=#{ granularity }&dailyAlignment=0&alignmentTimezone=America%2FNew_York&start=#{startTime}&end=#{endTime}"
  puts myurl
  response =HTTParty.get(URI::encode(myurl))
  #{"time"=>"2016-06-03T20:00:00.000000Z", "openBid"=>1.1355, "openAsk"=>1.13564, "highBid"=>1.13727, "highAsk"=>1.13752, "lowBid"=>1.13541, "lowAsk"=>1.13554, "closeBid"=>1.13651, "closeAsk"=>1.13684, "volume"=>2523, "complete"=>true}
  response
end
```

the ending website url is valid however when I use this code. The full output of my code gives this:

```
https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument=EUR_USD&candleFormat=bidask&granularity=H1&dailyAlignment=0&alignmentTimezone=America%2FNew_York&start=2016-06-06T15%3A47%3A40Z&end=2016-06-08T21%3A53%3A44Z
```

Any idea why it doesnt work when run the method, but works when I just paste the URL? I thought it was an encoding problem, but I am definitely encoding the URL in the method.

Comment: I don't really know, but since it's so easy to try, I'd suggest *not* calling `URI::encode` and see what happens.

Comment: Don't construct URI query parameters with string interpolation/concatenation. That way lies only despair and madness. Since you're using HTTParty you don't need to—and shouldn't—do *any* manual encoding/escaping. Pass your query parameters to `HTTParty.get` as a Hash using the `:query` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said above in the comments, you're making things really difficult for yourself by trying to encode query parameters yourself and using interpolation/concatenation to build URLs.

I would guess that the problem is that you're encoding the query parameters individually using `CGI.escape` and then a second time *en masse* using `URI.encode`. In other words, you're double-encoding them.

Incidentally, `CGI.escape` and `URI.encode` do the same thing, more or less (and the former is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824126/whats-the-difference-between-uri-escape-and-cgi-escape)). It's not clear why you're using both, but that's moot because you shouldn't be using either. You should be letting HTTParty do it for you.

Give `HTTParty.get` a base URL and pass it a Hash of your (raw, i.e. not encoded) query parameters with the `:query` option and it will do all of the encoding for you, correctly. As a side-effect, it makes it possible to write much cleaner code:

```
require "httparty"
require "date"

DATETIME_FMT = "%FT%TZ" # RFC 3339
BASE_URI = "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles"

DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
  instrument: "EUR_USD",
  candleFormat: "bidask",
  granularity: "H1",
  dailyAlignment: 0,
  alignmentTimezone: "America/New_York",
}.freeze

def get_data(start_time, end_time)
  params = DEFAULT_PARAMS.merge(
    start: start_time.strftime(DATETIME_FMT),
    end: end_time.strftime(DATETIME_FMT)
  )

  HTTParty.get(BASE_URI, query: params)
end

start_time = DateTime.new(2016, 6, 6, 15, 47, 40)
end_time = DateTime.now

hist_data = get_data(start_time, end_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for that incredibly thorough answer, it works perfectly.