# How to get params for url with whitespace as '%20' instead of '+' in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-encoding

If I have this params for adding to the URL

`params = { name: 'John Key' }`

and use the method `to_param`:

```
params.to_param
 => "name=John+Key"
```

The point is that '+' is not correctly read by the service used and is needed '%20' instead `name=John%20Key`: [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20/2678602#2678602)

Is there a way to return the params with '%20' without using `gsub`?

Comment: You misread the answers to the question linked. In _query_ plus signs are perfectly valid, treated as spaces and therefore there is no such redundant Rails helper existing.

Comment: I need the params for a url of typeform. It does not treat well the '+', but it does with '%20'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend just sticking to the use of a `gsub`, perhaps with a comment to explain the need for such behaviour.

While you *could* solve the problem by use of `URI.escape`, it is supposedly deprecated, as it does not fully conform to RFC specs. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059657/1954610) for a great write-up on it.

`Hash#to_param` is an alias of `Hash#to_query`, which calls `Object#to_query`. The simplest example to demonstrate this `+` vs `%20` issue is:

```
'John Key'.to_query(:name) # => "name=John+Key"
```

The implementation of `Object#to_query` is:

```
def to_query(key)
  "#{CGI.escape(key.to_param)}=#{CGI.escape(to_param.to_s)}"
end
```

And so, we find that:

```
CGI.escape("John Key") # => "John+Key"
```

Hence, this is why I have referenced the differences between `CGI.escape` and `URI.escape`.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
URI.encode 'John Smith'
# => John%20Smith
```

Answer (score 3):

not really.

Suggest using: `your_params_hash.to_query.gsub("+", "%20")`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `uri`?  e.g.

`require 'uri'
URI.escape('John Smith')`

The result in this example should be `John%20Smith`

Realized from other post that URI.escape is technically deprecated.  Where `h` stands for hash, and `k` is the key in the hash, try this:

`params.keys.inject({}) {|h, k| h[k] = ERB::Util.url_encode(params[k]); h }`

Comment: Yes, it works for the value of a param. But in this case I want to get a group of params with '%20'. Like to_param method but not returning the whitespaces with '+'  ```name=John%20Key```

Comment: FYI URI.escape has been depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Julie's answer to achieve the string of encoded values rather than a hash.

With the depreciation of `URI.encode` it is possible to achieve this with `ERB::Util.url_encode`, however you need to encode just the key and value pairs, not the full parameter, then join them together.

---

```
params = { name: 'John Key' }

# not what we want
ERB::Util.url_encode(params) # => "%7B%3Aname%3D%3E%22John%20Key%22%7D"
```

Here is a (pretty long) command that will work:

```
# Construct a new object (a string here) and build our params into it correctly.
# k = key of hash. 
# v = value of hash. 
# a = array created in each_with_object.

params.each_with_object([]) { |(k, v), a| a << [ERB::Util.url_encode(k), ERB::Util.url_encode(v)].join('=') }.join('&')

# => "name=John%20Key"
```

With more params:

```
params = { name: 'John Key', occupation: 'Web Developer!', 'Bad Key' => 'but works' }

params.each_with_object([]) { |(k, v), a| a << [ERB::Util.url_encode(k), ERB::Util.url_encode(v)].join('=') }.join('&')

# => "name=John%20Key&occupation=Web%20Developer%21&Bad%20Key=but%20works"
```

compared to Hash.to_query

```
params.to_query

# => "Bad+Key=but+works&name=John+Key&occupation=Web+Developer%21"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a literal percent encoding of a string without context (e.g. for [RFC 5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987) encoding of something like a `Content-Disposition` HTTP header's `filename*=...` value) then use of `URI.escape` / `URI.encode` (its alias) would have been correct. The [core library documentation's suggested replacements](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-escape) *ARE WRONG* in this case, as they are not equivalent:

- is converted to `+`, not `%20`
- `+` is converted to `%2B`, not left as `+`

Some posts about this suggest a `gsub` to hack the string back towards the original, but this is far simpler:

- https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB/Util.html#method-c-url_encode

...toggle source to see how it works - it's just a blunt encoder without context. That is *exactly what you sometimes want* when you know what you're doing, so let's hope it doesn't get removed from, or deprecated within the standard library.

If I get the time I intend to submit a patch to the core library docs that lists the *three* (not two) possible alternatives and gives more information on when you would use each of them. Right now, it's clear from the very large number of Google hits about this, and large number of at-best misleading answers, that the community is dangerously confused by the status quo.