# How to cgi escape ruby credentials

Tags: ruby

I am running the command bundle install and keep getting the following error

`Please CGI escape your usernames and passwords before setting them for authentication.`

I am unsure how I could go about CGI escaping my credentials- any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other `source` beside Rubygems configured in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: You may be able to find the answer on the page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645957/ruby-bundler-authentication-error

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in `irb` with Ruby's `CGI::Util` module:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require "cgi"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> CGI.escape "foo@example.com"
=> "foo%40example.com"
```

Comment: I get this same stupid error despite not using an email address ¯\_(ツ)_/¯