# Avoid double encoding when escaping URL fragments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, escaping, uri

I'm trying to clean up some auto-generated code where input URL fragments:

1. may include spaces, which need to be `%`-escaped (as `%20`, not `+`)
2. may include other URL-invalid characters, which also need to be `%`-escaped
3. may include path separators, which need to be left alone (`/`)
4. may include already-escaped components, which need *not* to be doubly-escaped

The existing code uses `libcurl` (via [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) and [Ethon](https://github.com/typhoeus/ethon)), which like command-line `curl` seems to happily accept spaces in URLs.

The existing code is all string-based and has a number of shenanigans involving removing extra slashes, adding missing slashes, etc. I'm trying to replace this with `URI.join()`, but this fails with `bad URI(is not URI?)` on the fragments with spaces.

The obvious solution is to use the (deprecated) `URI.escape`, which escapes spaces, but leaves slashes alone:

```rb
URI.escape('http://example.org/ spaces /<"punc^tu`ation">/non-ascïï /＆ｃ．')
# => "http://example.org/%20spaces%20/%3C%22punc%5Etu%60ation%22%3E/non-asc%C3%AF%C3%AF%20%F0%9D%96%88%F0%9D%96%8D%F0%9D%96%86%F0%9D%96%97%F0%9D%96%98/%EF%BC%86%EF%BD%83%EF%BC%8E"
```

This mostly works, except for case (3) above — previously escaped components get double-escaped.

```rb
s1 = URI.escape(s)
# => "http://example.org/%20spaces%20/%3C%22punc%5Etu%60ation%22%3E/non-asc%C3%AF%C3%AF%20%F0%9D%96%88%F0%9D%96%8D%F0%9D%96%86%F0%9D%96%97%F0%9D%96%98/%EF%BC%86%EF%BD%83%EF%BC%8E"
URI.escape(s)
# => "http://example.org/%2520spaces%2520/%253C%2522punc%255Etu%2560ation%2522%253E/non-asc%25C3%25AF%25C3%25AF%2520%25F0%259D%2596%2588%25F0%259D%2596%258D%25F0%259D%2596%2586%25F0%259D%2596%2597%25F0%259D%2596%2598/%25EF%25BC%2586%25EF%25BD%2583%25EF%25BC%258E"
```

The recommended alternatives to `URI.escape`, e.g. `CGI.escape` and `ERB::Util.url_encode`, are not suitable as they mangle the slashes (among other problems):

```rb
CGI.escape(s)
# => "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F+spaces+%2F%3C%22punc%5Etu%60ation%22%3E%2Fnon-asc%C3%AF%C3%AF+%F0%9D%96%88%F0%9D%96%8D%F0%9D%96%86%F0%9D%96%97%F0%9D%96%98%2F%EF%BC%86%EF%BD%83%EF%BC%8E"
ERB::Util.url_encode(s)
# => "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%20spaces%20%2F%3C%22punc%5Etu%60ation%22%3E%2Fnon-asc%C3%AF%C3%AF%20%F0%9D%96%88%F0%9D%96%8D%F0%9D%96%86%F0%9D%96%97%F0%9D%96%98%2F%EF%BC%86%EF%BD%83%EF%BC%8E"
```

Is there a clean, out-of-the-box way to preserve existing slashes, escapes, etc. and escape only **invalid** characters in a URI string?

So far the best I've been able to come up with is something like:

```rb
include URI::RFC2396_Parser::PATTERN

INVALID = Regexp.new("[^%#{RESERVED}#{UNRESERVED}]")

def escape_invalid(str)
  parser = URI::RFC2396_Parser.new
  parser.escape(str, INVALID)
end
```

This seems to work:

```rb
s2 = escape_invalid(s)
# => "http://example.org/%20spaces%20/%3C%22punc%5Etu%60ation%22%3E/non-asc%C3%AF%C3%AF%20%F0%9D%96%88%F0%9D%96%8D%F0%9D%96%86%F0%9D%96%97%F0%9D%96%98/%EF%BC%86%EF%BD%83%EF%BC%8E"
s2 == escape_invalid(s2)
# => true
```

but I'm not confident in the regex concatenation (even if it is the way `URI::RFC2396_Parser` works internally) and I know it doesn't handle all cases (e.g., a `%` that isn't part of a valid hex escape should probably be escaped). I'd much rather find a library standard solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059657/128421 might be helpful.

Comment: Where did you get those strings? Maybe we can just assume that the strings containing % are already escaped, and escape only those that have no %.

Comment: So, taking your 1/2/3 points at the top, you just want to handle spaces, and leave everything else alone. BTW, URL encoding uses `+` for spaces, although `%20` works too. So... why not just `s.gsub(' ', '+')`?

Comment: @Amadan the example I gave involves spaces, but I also need to handle `@`, non-ASCII characters, etc. I've updated accordingly.

Comment: @theTinMan I read that. It was helpful in reinforcing my general instinct to handle URL paths and query parameters separately.

Comment: @Aetherus That might not be a bad heuristic.