# undefined method `escape' for URI:Module in ruby 3

Tags: paperclip, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3

After updating my Rails application from Rails 6.0.1 to Rails 7.0.2.3

I am getting issue with the gem "paperclip", '~> 6.1.0'

while using it in application is gives error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `escape' for URI:Module
Did you mean?  escape_once):
```

Usage in my application:

```
<%= image_tag current_user.image.url('med'), width: "36px" %>
```

How to resolve this issue when bug is present in the ruby gemfile itself, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined method \`escape' for URI:Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174351/undefined-method-escape-for-urimodule)

Comment: yes idea is in both mokey patching is the technique used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution to this situation do a monkey patching to the missing method in library.

add a ruby filke uri_escape.rb inside the initializers folder:

add lines for monkey patching:

```
module URI
  def self.escape(url)
    encode_www_form_component(url)
  end
end
```

and its done.

Comment: CGI/URI escape are not the same:

URI.escape("www.google test.com")
 => "www.google%20test.com"
CGI.escape("www.google test.com")
 => "www.google+test.com"

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this problem due to the now-deprecated "paperclip" gem, and you don't want to switch to ActiveStorage yet, there is a solution:
The kt-paperclip gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/kt-paperclip) is a fork of Paperclip.

They have fixed this URI issue and switching to kt-paperclip will solve the above paperclip error and allow you to continue without migrating to ActiveStorage.