# undefined method `escape' for URI:Module in Rails 7 with gravatar_image_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

undefined method `escape' for URI:Module

```
  URI.escape(value, Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))
     ^^^^^^^
```

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
            <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
            <div class="modal-body p-5 pt-0">
                <form class="">
                    <div class="form mb-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <%if resource.avatar.attached? %>
                                <%= image_tag resource.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100!"), class: "rounded-circle" %>
                                <%else%>

                                <%= image_tag gravatar_image_url(current_user.email, size: 100), class: "rounded-circle" %>

                                <%end%>
                            </div>
```

issue is here

```
<%= image_tag gravatar_image_url(current_user.email, size: 100), class: "rounded-circle" %>
```

Tried some option to resolve the escape but don't work at all. Not sure if this is the gravatar_image_tag gem issue or some issues with my setup.

Comment: What's your ruby version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined method \`escape' for URI:Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174351/undefined-method-escape-for-urimodule)

Comment: I'm using Ruby 3.1.2 and trying to fix but not solved yet

Answer (score 0):

`URI#escape` was deprecated and later removed - https://github.com/ruby/uri/commit/61c6a47ebf1f2726b60a2bbd70964d64e14b1f98

From the commit :

```
# This method is obsolete and should not be used. Instead, use
# CGI.escape, URI.encode_www_form or URI.encode_www_form_component
# depending on your specific use case.
```

Ruby 3.0.0 onwards `URI#escape` does not work.

Use `CGI.escape` or `URI.encode_www_form` as mentioned in the deprecation note

**Update**

There is already a pull request raised on the `gravatar_image_tag` gems GitHub repository https://github.com/mdeering/gravatar_image_tag/pull/35

You can either fork the repository and use the gem from git

Or

create your own helper method as mentioned here - https://github.com/mdeering/gravatar_image_tag/pull/35#issuecomment-727137023

```rb
hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email)
"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}.png?height=#{size}&width=#{size}"
```

Comment: Thank you sir but not sure where can I apply CGI.escape with gravatar_image_tag gem I'm using

Comment: The fix is already raised on the master - https://github.com/mdeering/gravatar_image_tag/pull/35

Comment: You can fork and use it from github

Comment: or create a helper method of your own - https://github.com/mdeering/gravatar_image_tag/pull/35#issuecomment-727137023