# undefined method `encode' for URI:Module with gem Rspotify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri, spotify, urlencode

I am using [gem rspotify](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify) to access spotify's api in my rails app. The rails version is 6.0.4 but most importantly the Ruby version is 3.0.0

I keep getting this error "undefined method `encode' for URI:Module" when I try to call the api methods. I have to stress that I do not get this error when I downgrade to Ruby 2.6.3. It seems like Ruby 3.0.0 has not support for URI encode. My users controller is the code sample below. I get the error with *spotify_user.country* and other api methods.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :spotify]

  def spotify
    spotify_user = RSpotify::User.new(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    spotify_user.country
  end
end
```

In config/application.rb

```
RSpotify::authenticate(ENV['SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET'])
```

In devise.rb, I have

```
require 'rspotify/oauth'

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :spotify, ENV['SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET'], scope: 
  'user-read-email playlist-modify-public user-library-read user-library-modify'
end
```

I will like to know if there is a solution for the error that does not involve downgrading the ruby version

Answer (score 14):

I upgraded from Ruby 2.4.5 to Ruby 3.0.2 and the solution for me was to replace

```
URI.encode
```

with

```
CGI.escape
```

Comment: Thanks, But they are not completely interchangeable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824126/whats-the-difference-between-uri-escape-and-cgi-escape

Answer (score 5):

`URI.encode` was an alias for `URI.escape` that was in turn considered (and reported) obsoleted for quite a while.

It would be better to see the backtrace for the error you ask about, but I guess it fails [here](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify/blob/1498bb3d20d9ec4abae6fff209e93c527ed84482/lib/rspotify/playlist.rb#L318).

As you can see [here](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify/search?q=.encode), RSpotify is not consistent and uses `URI.encode` in one place and `Addressable::URI.encode` in another. Chances are this was a conscious decision but at first glance it looks just like an accidental thing.

There are a couple of solutions for your problem:

1. Fork RSpotify, fix the issue (replace all occurrences of URI.encode with Addressable::URI.encode, for example) and create a PR to upstream. You can use your fixed fork in the meantime, if in a rush with the upgrade.
2. You can monkey-patch URI itself adding a removed `encode` method back. Not a good idea at all, but still an option...
3. Replace RSpotify with some other client. The most involving one so put here just for completeness :)

Answer (score 3):

In pure Ruby, for Ruby 3.X:

**URL-encode for whole URL:**

```rb
URI::Parser.new.escape
```

**URL-encode for URL component:**

```rb
CGI.escape
```

For examples, see [yard doc here](https://github.com/noraj/ctf-party/blob/master/lib/ctf_party/cgi.rb) and [tests here](https://github.com/noraj/ctf-party/blob/master/test/test_string_cgi.rb).