# inline and url-encode for whatsapp the result of code sequence (obviously multiple lined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a code which I preparing for [whatsapp web share feature](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app/?lang=en), which requires URL-encoded string.

I beat myself over the wall, trying figure out how to convert multiple rails code executed lines to that single one, to be URL-encoded.

Here is my original code I'm guessing to convert

```
- %w(offer_category).each do |attr|
  = "For your review the #{unit.send(attr)} market property unit"
= unit.beds? ? "#{unit.beds} br" : nil
/
= unit.bathrooms? ? "#{unit.bathrooms} bath" : nil
= unit.beachline? ? "walking beach area" : nil
= unit.variant
with total area
= cut_zeros(unit.square_total)
priced at
= unit.sale_flat_price
= " (SKU: #{unit.sku})"
%br
%br
By the link below you'll find Floor-Plans, Descriptions, Video, VR scenes and more..
%br
= unit_url(unit.short_id, host: web_host(current))
-# = "#{URI.encode(unit.uri_code, host: web_host(current))}"
%br
%br
- %w(delivery_stage).each do |attr|
  Delivery stage:
  = unit.send(attr)
%br
%br
- if unit.square_total.present?
  Total area:
  = cut_zeros(unit.square_total)
  %br
- if unit.square_plot.present?
  Plot area:
  = cut_zeros(unit.square_plot)
  %br
- if unit.square_covered.present?
  Covered:
  = cut_zeros(unit.square_covered)
  %br
- if unit.ceiling_height.present?
  Ceiling height:
  = cut_zeros(unit.ceiling_height)
```

It generates what web browser expected:

```
Introducing the residence redefining living bla-bla..

For your review the primary market property unit 2 br 1 bath apartment with total area 63m² priced at € 90 500 (SKU: 1)

B y the link below you'll find Floor-Plans, Descriptions, Video, VR scenes and more..
https://subdomain.gtld.com/en/uniq/uri_code_35103

Delivery stage: Ready

Total area: 63m²
Covered: 58m²
Basement area: 5m²
Veranda covered: 4m²
Veranda uncovered: 2m²
```

But how to convert it to this?
I'm end and manually tried to make this, but its unsupported horror...

```
https://wa.me/?text=It%20might%20be%20interesting.%0D%0A%0D%0AIn%20short%3A%20#{(group.title).gsub(/\s/, '%20')}%0D%0A%0D%0AProject%20combines%20#{group.unit_variants.map{ |unit_case| unit_case.plural_name}.join(", ").gsub(/\s/, '%20')}%0D%0ABedrooms%20variations%3A%20#{group.bedrooms.map{ |bedroom| bedroom}.join(", ").gsub(/\s/, '%20')}
```

to be able to make a normal href link and but it on public

Answer (score 0):

This code should work on your case and give you flexibility to add variables on your params.

```rb
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
params = { :limit => 10, :page => 3 }
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

Comment: thanks. tried to read but a lot for me to figure out. 
could you give bit more detail, how to proceed with my code?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an easier way. Could you try it?