# Rails: how to escape "space" in Rails generated URL search string as %20 instead of +

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cgi

I have a search field in a Rails App. It is implemented this way:

```
<%= text_field_tag :searchAny, params[:searchAny_params], placeholder: "Search", id: "search_input", class: "search-field" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, id: "search-button", class: "search-button" %>
```

When I search for strings, which contain spaces such as: `find something`, I get `find something` in params, which is then rendered in the url as `find+something`. To my knowledge spaces used to be escaped through +, but now they should be escaped through %20.

I very much would like to switch to %20 in my url, because I access the query string in my frontend in order to make it available to new search functions or parse it somewhere and would need the + sign as a viable query string. Currently I am unable to search for `house+` or `+`, because the JS function I wrote splits the search string and currently has to replace `+` with `space`.

```
var searchquery = searchParams.split('?').pop().split('&').pop().split('=')[1].replace(/[+]/g, ' ');
```

After my refactoring I hope to get the search string part of my url with %20 for space and leave + available.

```
var searchquery = searchParams.split('?').pop().split('&').pop().split('=')[1].replace(/%20/, ' ');
```

How can I change how params are escaped in the search string?

I hope someone can put me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

### Addition

Currently my Rails app produces the following URL:

```
https://www.domain.tld/collection/opac?searchAny=find+something
```

I would prefer the query string to be already % escaped:

```
https://www.domain.tld/collection/opac?searchAny=find%20something
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to parse the query string. It will properly decode all characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059657/19312729), you can use the [Addressable](http://rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/2.2.4/Addressable/URI#encode-class_method) gem. Or alternatively you can try using Javascript's [encodeUri()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) to handle the URL encoding from the front-end side. For example:

```
document.getElementById('search_button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var searchInput = document.getElementById("search_input");
    var encodedQuery = encodeURI(searchInput.value)
    // continue to use the encodedQuery as search query
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. The Addressable gem sounds promising. How can I implement it in order to configure how params are escaped in the url?

Comment: If you simply want spaces to be escaped into %20 instead of +, you just need to use [Addressable::URI.encode()](https://rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/2.2.4/Addressable/URI#encode-class_method).

Comment: Could you please give me a hint where I would have to put it? I thought about it, but have no idea where.

Comment: I tried the JS way, but it already escapes the params I send to the backend for my database queries. I am looking for a way, how to configure how params with spaces are encoded in the resulting URL, when the search result is displayed in the client. Usually the URL is produced by routes.rb.

Comment: Existing encoding or escape functions already have a fixed rule on what escape character to use so you can't manually configure the params to tailor it for you specific need.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I guess I could escape the request in the client and deescape it on the server side  before making any database search queries. I will leave it for now the way it is.